# In python what is the correct nomenclature for accessing a class attribute using dot notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

This is semantics question, I'm writing a tutorial for a module that I hacked together for my lab and I would like to know if there is a correct term for accessing a class attribute by using dot notation. For example:

```
class funzo:
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.attribute = string
fun = funzo("Sweet sweet data")
fun.attribute
```

> Now one can access the string by ??? the object named fun.

I've been using the term 'dot referencing' but that seems wrong. I googled around and checked the python glossary but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: «Now one can access the string by accessing the attribute attribute of the object named fun.»

Comment: @Daniel double _attribute_ alert.

Comment: accessor or getter - and with Python I usually hear this standard OOP term as "accessor" (even with other languages getter usually refers to a method over property or attribute) - [this question covers it in more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706935/correct-way-to-use-accessors-in-python)

Comment: I'd argue you don't need another verb: "Now one can access the string via the `fun` object's `attribute` attribute". A *Python* tutorial might need some way to describe or name the act of accessing an attribute, but a module tutorial can assume enough familiarity with Python to assume the reader already knows how.

Comment: @chepner that's the rub I'm trying to describe this to scientists with little to no python or OOP background so I try to make everything as simple as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute Access, this is from the language reference section on [customizing it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access):

> The following methods can be defined to customize the meaning of *attribute access* (use of, assignment to, or deletion of `x.name`) for class instances.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So your quote could be better worded as:

> Now, one can access the attribute `attribute` by using dotted expressions on the instance named `fun`.

Where the term *dotted expressions* is found from the entry on 'attribute' in the [Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

Another choice employed in the docs as an alternative to *dotted expressions* is, as in your title, *dot-notation*. This is found in the *Callables* section of the [Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), so another option you could consider is:

> Now, one can access the attribute `attribute` using dot-notation on the instance named `fun`.

Both are, in my opinion, completely understandable if someone has at least some experience in programming languages. I prefer the term *dot-notation* and as such, would use the later.