# finding _collections in python source

Tags: python

I wanted to have a look at the python deque class. When I checked [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/791034a0ae1e/Lib/collections/__init__.py) , I found the following at line 10

```
 from _collections import deque, defaultdict
```

where exactly can I find this _collections module? I searched on my copy of the python source, but couldn't spot it.

Where is this class located?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`_collections` is builtin extension module.

You can find source for _collection module [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c).

[Setup.dist](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/Setup.dist) contains mapping between builtin extension module name to source file.

Answer (score 1):

`_collections` is a private implementation of a class according to this answer: ["Private" (implementation) class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551038/private-implementation-class-in-python).

Being private, I don't think that you will be able to access its Python source but you can check out the C implementation [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/20557286cc35/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c).

Comment: In this case, `_collections` is a module implemented in C to support the main `collections` python module; because it needs to be a distinct, separate module an 'internal' name is used. It is but an implementation detail, after all, not part of the public API.

Answer (score 1):

These days the CPython source code (including built-in modules) is [hosted on Github](https://github.com/python/cpython), so you can find the collections module source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c).

For the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) module, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py).