# Python 2.7: applying str to collections.Counter and collections.defaultdict

Tags: python, python-2.7

collections.Counter and collections.defaultdict are both inherited from dict. So what is the difference between them which causes non-similar output ('class' and 'type')?

```
import collections

print str(collections.Counter)
print str(collections.defaultdict)
```

Output:

```
<class 'collections.Counter'>
<type 'collections.defaultdict'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your answer here boils down to something rather boring: `Counter` is written in Python and `defaultdict` is written in C.

Here's [`collections.py`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py). Notice you can scroll down and find a standard class definition for `Counter`:

```
########################################################################
###  Counter
########################################################################

class Counter(dict):
    '''Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
    or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
    are stored as dictionary values.
    ...
    '''
```

However, `defaultdict` is imported from `_collections`:

```
from _collections import deque, defaultdict
```

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075267/2588818), that's a built-in extension written in C.

You'll notice you get this same behavior if you string-ify `deque` (also C) or some other class from `collections` written in Python:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> str(deque)
"<type 'collections.deque'>"
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> str(OrderedDict)
"<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"*
```