# Python External Classes

Tags: python, class, external, python-module

It looks simple, but I could not find a solution.

I display the problem below with the simplest example I could come up with.

(My classes are quiet more complex ;) )

**file A.py**

```
import os, sys
import B
from B import *
class _A():
    def __init__(self,someVars):
        self.someVars = someVars
    def run(self):
        print self.someVars

someVars = 'jdoe'
B._B(someVars)
```

---

**file B.py don't match with import A**

```
import A
from A import _A
class _B():
    def __init__(self,someVars):
        self.someVars = someVars
    def run(self):
        A._A(self.someVars)
```

with `import A` -> callback : cannot find _A

It only works when I do -

```
from A import *
```

But and logically A functions are executed 2 times.

Thanks to all

Comment: Its because import A doesn't import underscored classes. You are calling `A._A` instead of `_A`, when you do `from A import _A` its allowing you to call `_A` directly. Never use `from A import *`, always either use `import A` or `from A import _A`. You don't need both either, one will do. [Underscored Class imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551038/private-implementation-class-in-python). [Import vs. from import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to first `import X`, then `from X import Y`. If you need Y (even if `Y` is `*`) do just `from X import Y`. This might be the cause of 2 times execution.

Also why have cyclic dependencies between modules `A -> B, B -> A`? Maybe they should be in one file then?

Answer (score 0):

Because of cyclic dependency you are facing the import error, you can continue your work as:

*File A.py:*

```
import os, sys
#Below two import lines does cyclic dependency between file A and B which is wrong and will give import error, 
#commenting below two lines will resolve your import error
#import B 
#from B import * 
class _A():
    def __init__(self,someVars):
        self.someVars = someVars
    def run(self):
        print self.someVars

someVars = 'jdoe'
#B._B(someVars) #comment and respective logic should be moved in B file
```

Also, you should either use `import A` or `from A import _A` and if you use the later you should call the class directly as: `_A(self.someVars)` not as: `A._A(self.someVars)`, this calling convention will be used for former import style(`import A`), for better understanding of external use of classes and module, you can refer following link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html