# Error in compiling C code with variable name new with g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

We are trying a modify some existing C projects i.e. we are trying to make some C++ function calls from the C code. We tried changing compiler from gcc to g++ but there were several compilation errors because of incompatibality. What we are trying to do is to call some C++ functions in C code without making any change to existing code. Simply changing the compiler didn't seem to do the trick. Hence we tried following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    int func(int new ) {
        printf("in new func()\n");
    }
}
```

When i compile it using command

> g++ -c hello.c -o hello

we get following errors

```
hello.c:9: error:expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘new’.
```

Now we are aware that new is c++ keyword. As mentioned before, we are trying not to make any modifications to existing C code. Any suggestions ?

These aren't the only errors. There are other errors related to structure declaration.

> attr.c:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

At attr.c, line 75 is

> static post_op_attr error_attr = {.attributes_follow = FALSE };

The problem is that there are other C styled structure declaration and initialization done in the code so even if we rename the variable name, we would still have to modify other parts of the C program. Hence we are looking for a way to add C++ function calls to C code without modifying existing C code.

Comment: If you don't want to make any modifications to the C code, why not carry on compiling it as C? From C++ you just need `extern "C"` declarations of the functions that you need to call.

Comment: To clarify Charles' point, note that in the declaration within your `C++` program, you don't need to give the argument a name.

Comment: @BoBTFish Nor is it necessary in C.

Comment: To OP: "Error in compiling C code with with g++" - exactly, that's an error. C code should only compiled with a C compiler, which g++ isn't, because it's a C++ compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3 True, but I was trying to point out that at the point where you *declare* it (which will be in `C++` code), you don't need to give it a name. At the *definition*, the name is necessary, but this is ok as it will be in `C` code.

Answer (score 7):

`new` is a keyword so you can't call a variable `new`. But even if you could I'm not sure why you would because it is incredibly hard to read.

Even though you are using `extern "C"` you are still compiling with `g++` which is the c++ compiler and it is going to complain about this.

Basically C code cannot always run unchanged in c++ because c++ introduced some keywords. This is one of those times where you have no choice but to change some of the existing code C code to get it to compile as c++ code.

Comment: Sorry, Understand now

Comment: if we dont use c++ compiler i.e g++ we wont be able to use C++ functions in the existing C code.

Comment: @user3114360 : That's because C is a different language than C++.  If you want to convert your C to C++, then now's the time to fix the variable names.

Comment: @user3114360 I thought you didn't want to change the existing `C` code at all? If you are changing it anyway (to add some calls to `C++` functions), just change the name.

Comment: The answer is just to change the old C code to not have any c++ keywords in it. You really don't have any other choice I'm afraid.

Comment: @shuttle87 The preprocessor gives him a choice. It's not a pleasant one, though.

Comment: @Roddy, I think preprocessing `new` to be something else then risks breaking c++ code, but even if it didn't it really seems like a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: @shuttle87: The preprocessor solution can/should be restricted to the "C" part of the source.

Answer (score 3):

As you say `new` is a C++ keyword, so can't be used as a variable name.

If your C code is calling C++ functions, than you should really take the view that it isn't C and more, but C++. And that will mean more (much, much more  if you want to make it idiomatic C++) then just replacing a few badly named variables.

But, if you're intent on minimal changes to your C codebase, you could try this hack:

```
#define new new__
```

But, I *really* wouldn't recommend that as a long term fix.

Comment: While the `#define` will probably work on most compilers, it is illegal from a Standard `C++` point of view. So if you *do* use this, you aren't writing `C++` any more (although it will probably work).

Comment: static post_op_attr error_attr = {.attributes_follow = FALSE }; error is : attr.c:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token The problem is that there are other C styled structure declaration and initialization done in the code so even if we rename the variable name, we would still have to modify other parts of the C program

Comment: @user3114360, Well, that's a different problem. Those new-fangled C99 struct initializers aren't going to play nicely with C++.

Comment: @Roddy Well is there any compiler flag related to it to solve that, or any other solution ??

Comment: @BoBTFish Only illegal if you're using C++ standard library, if I understand this correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109377/is-it-legal-to-redefine-a-c-keyword

Comment: @Roddy If you are looking at Alok Save's answer, he doesn't say so, but his quote is from the 2003 Standard. In The (current, 2011) Standard, the wording has changed: `17.6.4.3.1 Macro names [macro.names] ... 2 A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the attribute-tokens described in 7.6.`

Comment: Also, it says "A translation unit that includes a header", not "a **standard** header". Which is odd anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is keyword, do not use g++ if you do not want to modify the code.
Use `gcc` instead.

Note: if it's c code, it should never include `extern "C"`, if it's c++ code, it should never use `new` as variable.

Comment: static post_op_attr error_attr = {.attributes_follow = FALSE };

error is :

attr.c:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token         
The problem is that there are other C styled structure declaration and initialization done in the code so even if we rename the variable name, we would still have to modify other parts of the C program

Answer (score 1):

The rules in C++ for identifiers are :

1.Only Alphabets,Digits and Underscores are permitted.

2.Identifier name cannot start with a digit.

```
3.Key words cannot be used as a name.
```

4.Upper case and lower case letters are distinct.

5.Special Characters are not allowed

6.Global Identifier cannot be used as “Identifier”.

EDIT: regarding your requirement to call C++ functions from C code, without modifying the C code,

one way is to write a wrapper around your C++ code in C and then compile with gcc, it is not easy to call c code directly from g++ as discussed here :

[How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

also you might like to see this:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mix-c-and-cpp/

http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~beardj/Mixed_C_C++.html

and also

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/c-calls-cpp.html

Comment: static post_op_attr error_attr = {.attributes_follow = FALSE }; error is : attr.c:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token The problem is that there are other C styled structure declaration and initialization done in the code so even if we rename the variable name, we would still have to modify other parts of the C program

Comment: @Raheel: Indeed. No amount of magic is going to turn a C99 program into C++11. The two languages forked in the early 90s. Today they're mostly link-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Every computer language has some reserve keywords which it doesn't allow to be used as variable names. Here is a list of c language reserved key words which you should not use as variable names http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_reserved_keywords.htm

One more thing as you are compiling on a c++ compiler so you should also avoid using c++ reserved keywords here is a link for c++ keywords http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_keywords.html

Change `new` with something else like change `new` with `num` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are different language, so it makes not much sense to compiler C code with a C++ compiler.

But you don't need to, people do combine C and C++ in different compilation units on a daily base. Just create a common header file `toto.h` that you will include in both. Have all functions there inside an `extern "C"` clause that you make invisible for C and visible for C++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

   // your function declarations (not definitions) go here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now you can implement your functions in separate compilation units (.c files). And these functions may call each other without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Migrated from your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655100/error-compiling-c-code-using-c-compiler/20655228#20655228).

### What extern "C" does

`extern "C"` will not make that code to be treated as a C code, it's just a linkage option.

Check [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/1207195) for more information about what it means. To make it short (and simple) it changes how function name is stored in binary files (C++ compiler mangles - *decorate* - function names because of function overloads: same name but different parameters). You'll need it only when you're linking a C library to a C++ module (or when you're exporting a C interface from your C++ module).

### C and C++ compilers

Because you're using a C++ compiler (g++ is C++ GCC frontend, confused? Take a look to this post about [what's difference between gcc and g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)) your file will be compiled as C++ code and you can't use C++ keywords (as posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653345/1207195)).

### Solution

To compile C source files (assuming you can't simply call `gcc` C frontend) using `g++` C++ frontend you have to use `-std=c99` (see [this documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) for C99 GCC support).

```
g++ -c -std=c99 hello.c -o hello
```