# Error C1189 #error: The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing the keyword "inline"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, migration, visual-studio-2019, inline

I am migrating a project from VS 2010 to VS2019. My code is working fine in VS 2010 while I am getting error in VS2019 for the same code.

```
#undef inline
#define inline __forceinline

..///
..///code 

#undef inline
#define inline inline
```

`Error  C1189   #error:  The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing the keyword "inline". Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden define`

How can I  remove this error.

Comment: You can't `#define` a C++ keyword. They are all reserved identifiers. You eliminate the error message by removing `#define inline __forceinline`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I believe the standard says that it's UB to redefine a keyword if you include any standard library headers. It doesn't say it's always UB. That being said, it's pretty hard to not include any standard library headers.

Comment: @Brian I see questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109377/is-it-legal-to-redefine-a-c-keyword) that agree with you, but it dates back to C++11 and [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.key#1) identifies keywords as reserved while [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.name#3) forbids the use of reserved identifiers with no conditions on the presence of headers. Is the information in your comment still current? Am I misreading the standard?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think that in that context, "identifier" should be read as referring to a type of token. Before translation phase 7, `inline` would only be a preprocessing token, not a token, so the rule would not apply. However I agree the standard is not awfully clear about this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The rule about headers is still present [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/macro.names#2). It would be redundant if a general prohibition on redefining keywords existed.

Comment: @Brian My reading of the linked passage is that keywords are always forbidden from being `#define`d. The condition that a standard header must be included is only included in the first line, which prohibits `#define`ing identifiers declared in standard headers rather than keywords. It would then always be forbidden to `#define inline`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But see [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#overview-1) which seems to limit the scope to "programs that use the facilities of the C++ standard library".

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot for the follow up. I didn't know about that section.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by adding **_XKEYCHECK_H** to the `Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`. 
**reference**: [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21af5654-7ab6-4eee-87d5-d3ce4f714ccd/latest-version-of-vs-2017-fails-to-compile-with-error-c-standard-library-forbids-macroizing?forum=vcgeneral)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `_ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS` to the preprocessor definition can also solve the problem.