# Python import statements in complex package structures?

Tags: python, import

Consider the following hierarchy of three regular packages and their
contents:

```
quick
├── brown
│   ├── fox.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── lazy
│   ├── dog.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

Now suppose there is a function `jump` in module `dog` and it is needed in module `fox`.  How should I proceed?

Having   recently   seen    Raymond   Hettinger's   [talk   at   Pycon
2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) I  would the  like
the function to be directly importable from the root of package `lazy`,
like this:

```
from lazy import jump
```

Also, it seems to me that writing relative imports is more concise and
makes the intra-package connections easily visible. Hence, I'd write
this into `lazy/__init__.py`:

```
from .dog import jump
```

And this into `fox.py`:

```
from ..lazy import jump
```

But I wonder, is this the right way?

First, importing the name `jump` in `lazy/__init__.py` does nothing to
prevent it from being imported directly from `dog`.  Can it cause problems if a function is potentially imported from many places?  For instance, in unit testing, can we possibly monkey patch the name from a wrong location?

Moreover, IDEs with their auto-import routines seem to prefer importing from the module where the function is defined.  I could perhaps override this by putting character `_` in front of all module names, but this seems a bit impractical.

Is it otherwise dangerous to bring all names that are needed outside a
package to `__init__.py`?  Probably this at least increases the
possibility of circular imports.  But I guess that if a circular
import is encountered there is something fundamentally wrong with the
package structure anyway.

What about the relative imports?
[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says that
absolute imports are recommended:  what does it mean when it says that absolute
imports behave better than the relative ones?  Can you give me an
example?

Comment: Are you sure `jump` belongs in `dog.py`, and not higher up in the hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking `lazy` as some sort of a coherent collection of components, some of which are needed also elsewhere in `quick`.

Comment: I would recommend be explicit, keep it as simple as possible.  Intra-package imports can get a bit crazy over time.  So forget all the `__init__.py` magic.  If you really want to, you could do that for external user visible names only in the top level `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explicit interface declaration**: If you want to expose the `jump` function as belonging to the `lazy` package, then it makes sense to include it `lazy.__init__` , as you suggest. That way you're making it clear that it is part of `lazy`'s "*public interface*". You're also suggesting the other modules are not part of the public interface.

**On preventing people/tools from importing it directly from `dog`**: In Python, privacy is up to the consent of the user, you can't forcibly hide anything, but there are conventions.

Using underscores and defining `dog._jump()` makes it clear that `dog` doesn't *want* to expose `_jump`. And we could assume that any IDE tools should respect this type of convention. At any rate, if `dog` defines `_jump`, and `lazy` exposes `jump`, then you won't have the problem of not knowing which is imported, because the names are different, so this is explicit, which is considered good in Python.

Here's a nice pointer on this topic: [Defining private module functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547145/defining-private-module-functions-in-python)

**On relative imports:**: those are discouraged by PEP 8, however they were implemented for a reason, and they replaced implicit relative imports. The reason in PEP 8: *especially when dealing with complex package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily verbose*.

**Final thoughts**: in short, if you consider the `lazy` package to be a library and don't want to expose the internal modules, then I think it makes sense to expose the objects in `lazy.__init__`. If on the contrary you want people to know there is a `dog` module, then by all means, let other modules do:

`from lazy.dog import jump`

or

`from ..lazy import jump`

If `brown` and `brown.fox` will always be packaged and are tightly integrated with `lazy` then I don't see the difference between absolute and relative, but I would slightly prefer relative, to explicitly indicate you're referring to an internal module.

But if you think they could be split in the future, then relative import doesn't make sense and you'd rather do, depending on the above points:

`from lazy.dog import jump` 
or: 
`from lazy import jump`

Comment: This is a nicely organized answer.  It clarifies well some of my
concerns, but I can't really see an obvious way to do this (as
[The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
suggests).

Comment: Also, I think that defining functions like `jump` as internal like `_jump` is a bit
clumsy because then I would have to define almost everything as
internal.  But there is a point as you say, because then the
names would be different.

Comment: I guess there's no "obvious" way in the sense of The Zen of Python, because Python supports both ways. Here they kind of muddied that principle. 

I suggest you look at several standard packages to get an idea of the best practices. For instance, the xml package makes use of relative imports (limited to one dot such as `from .xmlreader import InputSource`), and also includes some classes into the package's `__init__.py` file, and defines variables and classes with an `_` to mark them as private. 

Most other standard packages don't do that and have an empty `__init__.py`.