# Python: How to define variables in global space without defining them as globals

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, global

I am declaring a global list, and as part of the list element definition, I need to reference some obscure data from other modules. I would like to declare some simple short-hand references to these external variables right before declaring the list, but I don't want these reference variables to become global variables.

This all probably sounds very confusing, so here is an example:

```
prj = book.OverrideLevel.PROJECT
ent = book.OverrideLevel.ENTITY
elm = book.OverrideLevel.ELEMENT

list = [OvrType( 3, prj, "OutTypes" ),
        OvrType( 4, prj, "FilePrefix" ),
        OvrType( 5, ent, "FileSuffix" ),
        OvrType( 6, ent, "World" ),
        OvrType( 7, ent, "Anim" ),
        OvrType( 8, ent, "Armature" ),
        OvrType( 9, ent, "MeshData" ),
        OvrType( 10, elm, "General" ),
        OvrType( 11, elm, "ObjPrefix" ),
        OvrType( 12, elm, "ObjSuffix" ) ]
```

In the example, I want to avoid defining any globals other than `list`. Since this is happening in the global scope, `prj`, `ent`, and `elm` will also become global variables. Is there any way to avoid this in Python? Perhaps by defining the list as empty (`list = []`), then creating a +1 scope, and defining the list contents there? I'm just not sure how to do this.

One thing I've considered is to create a function, then call it immediately:

```
list = []
def BuildList():

    prj = book.OverrideLevel.PROJECT
    ent = book.OverrideLevel.ENTITY
    elm = book.OverrideLevel.ELEMENT

    global list    
    list = [OvrType( 3, prj, "OutTypes" ),
            .... ]

BuildList()
```

Would there be a better way? I know some languages allow you to add scopes manually for any reason needed. But since Python is so text-driven (spacing=scope), I wasn't sure if something like that would be permitted.

I appreciate any advice

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547145/5987 helps.

Comment: Do you mean to define the function as private?

Comment: Yes, private to the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to delete the variables from the global namespace when you no longer need them:

```
prj = book.OverrideLevel.PROJECT
ent = book.OverrideLevel.ENTITY
elm = book.OverrideLevel.ELEMENT

list = [OvrType( 3, prj, "OutTypes" ),
        OvrType( 4, prj, "FilePrefix" ),
        ...
       ]

del prj, ent, elm
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Thanks!