# How to avoid importing module private functions?

Tags: python

I am asking about module privates, not class privates.

Suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547160/10308337), a module private starts with one underscore, such a element is not copied along when using the **from <module_name> import** * form of the import command; it is however imported if using the **import <moudule_name>** syntax.

So the question is if I have to use **import <moudule_name>** syntax, how to avoid importing module private functions?

Comment: Just don't access `module_name._private` members.  The `_private` definitions will be executed regardless of whether you import them or not, so there's not any particular benefit to not importing them, just so long as you don't touch them.

Comment: You cannot prevent users from using it. @Samwise

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to avoid? You can *never* prevent users from using it. Python doesn't have access modifiers, and having a single underscore is all that is required conventionally.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess we can make it [harder](https://tio.run/##hVBLDoMgEN1ziukKSUwT7aYx6VmMH6gkCEShxtNTVNpareks5/1mnh5No@Tlqjs3cNOA0lRGuB1bVVtBz3rEMeABEyh6YBkCP7rj0kQYY1RTBj01VkckQzM2bTz@KAzNmZWV4UpOIIQJ2kA5YbLI7kKVhQBtS8GrtzBP4t0qXeVs2b@CZg4kPmiFbM47tkyPLdM/lqEX35FYOkK@sRgYF/TGiOOtVp2BV9EIfSrfv3UMpl/g7gznng) to access, though.

Comment: And maybe the private function could also inspect who's calling it and throw a tantrum if's an outsider.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i am looking for a way, if possible, to programmatically avoid importing module private functions. If there is no such way, I will use documentation to address what Samwise suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A feasible way is to create a separate folder for the module, add `__init__.py` file and import all the contents of the module.

We assume that the original structure is as follows:

```
.
├── module_a.py
└── test_module_a.py
```

Modify it to:

```
.
├── module_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── _module_a.py
└── test_module_a.py
```

The `__init__.py` file only imports the contents of the module a file using the asterisk syntax:

```
# module_a/__init__.py
from ._module_a import *
```

So when you are importing the `module_a`, the private function will not be visible because it has not been imported by the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: You meant storing all private functions in _module_a.py and adding a leading underscore for each of them?

Comment: @John No, the file content does not need to be modified. I modify the file name just to remind the user that it is protected.