# Private Variables and Methods in Python

Tags: python, private, private-members, private-methods, double-underscore

When should I use `_foo` (an underscore) or `__bar` (double underscore) for private members and methods in Python?

Comment: Thank you all. I found another topic which is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private

Comment: Better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Answer (score 72):

Please note that there is no such thing as "private method" in Python. Double underscore is just name mangling:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __foo(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> A.__dict__.keys()
['__dict__', '_A__foo', '__module__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
>>> a._A__foo()
```

So therefore `__` prefix is useful when you need the mangling to occur, for example to not clash with names up or below inheritance chain. For other uses, single underscore would be better, IMHO.

EDIT, regarding confusion on `__`, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is quite clear on that:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes
> that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with
> double leading underscores and no trailing underscores.  This invokes
> Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is
> mangled into the attribute name. **This helps avoid attribute name
> collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the
> same name.**
>
> Note 3: Not everyone likes name mangling.  Try to balance the
> need to avoid accidental name clashes with potential use by
> advanced callers.

So if you don't expect subclass to accidentally re-define own method with same name, don't use it.

Answer (score 44):

The double underscore. It mangles the name in such a way that it can't be accessed simply through `__fieldName` from outside the class, which is what you want to begin with if they're to be private. (Though it's still not very hard to access the field.)

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__privateField = 4;
        print self.__privateField # yields 4 no problem

foo = Foo()
foo.__privateField
# AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__privateField'
```

It will be accessible through `_Foo__privateField` instead. But it screams "I'M PRIVATE DON'T TOUCH ME", which is better than nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Double underscore. That mangles the name. The variable can still be accessed, but it's generally a bad idea to do so.

Use single underscores for semi-private (tells python developers "only change this if you absolutely must") and doubles for fully private.

Comment: Not quite right. A single underscore means you are tampering with undocumented properties of a object that are subject to change and you may well break the invariants maintained by the object so you should understand exactly what you are doing if you decide to break the object encapsulation.

Answer (score -4):

Because thats coding convention.
See [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

Comment: The OP was asking which one to use. Not why.