# What is the difference between "import pkg.a as a" and "from pkg import a"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two modules forming a circular import under a package

```
/test
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

a.py

```
import test.b
def a():
  print("a")
```

b.py

```
import test.a
def b():
  print("b")
```

But when I do "import test.a" from python interactive interpreter it throws AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'a'

```
>>> import test.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import test.b as b
  File "test/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import test.a as a
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'a'
```

But when I change it to `from test import a` and `from test import b`, it works fine.

So what is the difference?

I am using python3.5

---

Edit 1:

As asked by @Davis Herring, python2 behaves differently. 
when using `import test.a as a` format there is no error thrown.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test.a
```

However, when using `from test import a` it throws error

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from test import b
  File "test/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test import a
ImportError: cannot import name a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: You may want to square up your code and results.

Comment: Can you _also_ test with Python&nbsp;2?  I think the behavior [is different there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22397610/8586227), and we could cover both with one good answer.

Answer (score 1):

`import` does 3 things:

1. Find and load modules (typically from disk) not already in `sys.modules`.
2. *After* each newly loaded module finishes execution, assign it as an attribute on its containing package (if any).
3. Assign a variable in the scope of the `import` to allow access to the nominated module.

There are many tricks:

1. `import a.b` assigns a variable `a`, so that you can write `a.b` like in the import.
2. `import a.b as c` assigns `c` to be the module`a.b`, not `a` as before.
3. `from a import b` can select a module or *any other attribute* of `a`.
4. Step #1 of a circular import “succeeds” immediately because the relevant entries in `sys.modules` are created when the import *begins*.

Points #2 and #4 explain the failure with a circular `import a.b as b`: the circular import goes straight to step #3, but then the import attempts to load the attribute from step #2 of the *outer* import which has yet to occur.

The `from` ambiguity [used to cause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6351805/8586227) the same trouble, but a [special fallback](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636) to look in `sys.modules` was added in 3.5 to support this case.  The same approach would probably work for `import a.b as b`, but that hasn’t happened yet.