# Create an object given its class name as a dynamic string in Python

Tags: python, methods, arguments

Say I have these two classes:

tables.py

```
class Device79table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        #link to datasource
        model = Device79
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

models.py

```
class Device79(models.Model):
    # data for table
```

And I have a function which references both classes.

views.py

```
def function():
    #makes table of all objects in device 79
    table = Device79table(Device79.objects.all()) 
    table.draw()
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Assume the argument 'device' = Device79

```
def function(device)
    table = device+table(device.objects.all())
    table.draw()
```

This is so tables get drawn based on the value of device. I.e, device **could** be  Device79, Device80, Device81 etc.. and the program would draw the correct table automatically.

Comment: It is possible, but it's probably not what you want to do. Have you considered making a `dict` for all `device*table` objects?

Comment: Hey @mhlester, I haven't, but do you know what this type of problem is so I can google and understand the problem better? I'll look into making a dict in the meantime, cheers!

Comment: I decided to put it as an answer instead. See below

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `Device79table` is defined, but I'll make an assumption it's `global`

My fake definition of it:

```
def Device79Table(arg):
    print arg
```

Integrating that with your function:

```
def function(device):
    globals()[device + 'table'](device.objects.all())
    table.draw()
```

The `globals()` function returns a `dict` of all global objects, with keys a string of their name. So `globals()['Device79table']` is the same thing as `Device79table`

Comment: Hi @mhlester, Thanks so much for your answer! I've updated my question because i neglected to mention a couple of key pieces of information. I think your solution may still apply but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: So long as all the devices are defined the same way, it should still apply. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This is a new solution that takes into account the fact that you don't actually instantiate your classes, but work directly with the class objects.

Since `Device79` has to be defined before `Device79table.Meta`, you can't tell `Device79` which table to use during it's own definition. You can't even do it during `Device79table`, as it doesn't exist yet.

Therefore, you need to tell `Device79` which table to use *after* defining the corresponding table.

As you can see, I also choose not to use dynamic variable names, but a clearly defined object inside an other. Dynamic variable names makes your code harder to read and maintain.

**models.py**

```
class Device79(models.Model):
    table = None  # Optional, but cleaner.
```

**tables.py**

```
import models

class Device79table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        # link to datasource
        model = models.Device79
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"} 

# once the table is defined, we can tell Device79 which table to use.
models.Device79.table = Device79table
```

**views.py**

```
import tables  # "from tables import Device79table" would work too.
from models import Device79
# You need to import tables, even if you access the tables from the models,
# because this is where we tell the device which table to use.

def function(device)
    table = device.table(device.objects.all())
    table.draw() 

function(Device79)
```

Usually, circular imports aren't a problem, as long a you import modules and not single objects, but since you need to access your models directly during the definition of your tables, it makes it impossible to import the tables in `models.py`. This is why we alter the device in `tables.py` to tell it which table to use, instead of being able to set it directly in `models.py`.

This way, we keep the chain of import like this: `views -> tables -> models` and `models` never tries to import `tables`, but it also means that we have to import `tables` at least once somewhere to complete the models definition.

It's a little surprising, but I couldn't think of a cleaner and easier way to do this while only working with class objects and not instances.

Comment: Hi @Fury, Thanks so much for your answer! I've updated my question because i neglected to mention a couple of pieces of information. I tried your method and ended up with circular imports. Do you think you could nudge me in the right direction? :)

Comment: I didn't realise that you were actually working with class objects and not instances of those classes. It makes circular import impossible to solve (circular imports aren't truly a problem, usually. [See here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955790/python-circular-imports-once-again-aka-whats-wrong-with-this-design#3956038). But it is in your case. I found a solution, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python is particularly good in *reflection*. Provided your description, here's an example of what you could do:

In `models.py`:

```
class Device79:
    objects = "Device79.objects"
```

In `tables.py`:

```
class Device79table:
    def __init__(self, devices):
        self.devices = devices

    def draw(self):
        print "%s.draw() called with %s" % (self.__class__, self.devices)
```

Then in `views.py`:

```
import tables

def function(device):
    table = tables.__dict__[device.__name__ + 'table'](device.objects)
    table.draw()

import models
function(models.Device79)
```

or alternatively:

```
from models import Device79
function(Device79)
```