# Inheritance with tuple in python

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples

I am playing with inheritance with python but got stuck when I try to modify the properties of a tuple. This is what I did:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def add(self,number):
        self = tuple(list(self)+[number])
```

Now when I use

```
x = MyTuple()
x.add(23)
```

x doesn't changed to `(23)`, but is still `()`!
Am I doing something wrong or does this has to do something with hashing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subclass tuple object with ability to reinstantiate self internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306557/python-subclass-tuple-object-with-ability-to-reinstantiate-self-internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing something wrong that has nothing to do with hashing. Tuples are immutable, which means they do not change. When calling `tuple` you create a new tuple. You then assigned `self`, which is a function argument, and therefore a local variable. All that does is lose track of which object the `add` method was called on. The method then returns, causing the new tuple to be deleted.

By the way, why did you even make lists? Tuples can be added.

Comment: as per my knowledge tuples cannot be added, how do you add them?

Comment: @YannVernier: they do not change because they were defined this way (methods for mutability raising errors or not existing), but he added a function that would recreate a tuple to replace self. Why would it not work? Because he doesn't return self? Otherwise, there is nothing in tuple definition that prevent self itself from being changed.

Comment: @Tarptaeya: You just add these with + operation.

Comment: It's the typical confusion between names and objects. `self` is the name of a local variable, which holds a reference; the object it refers to is remains when you make `self` point to another. `x` is another name for that original object and completely independent of `self`. The object itself also never changes because not only didn't anyone try, it is immutable which means incapable of change.

Comment: You add (concatenate actually, but we reused the + symbol) tuples exactly like lists, the only difference is the syntax to create a single-entry tuple: `x+(23,)` because the parenthesis wouldn't make a tuple without the comma.