# Working with classes and setters and getters

Tags: python, class, oop

> I need to Create a class called Color.
>
> - Code 1 constructor
> - That requires 2 parameters
> - Code 2 properties
> - 1 property is public
> - 1 property is private
> - Create an accessor and setter for the 1 private property
> - Instantiate the class created above
> - Output the two properties

I believe I have been able to create the class and as well the constructor but where am having my issues is the public/private properties as well as the other parts are troubling me.

```py
class Color:
   def __init__(self,full_name,birthday ):
       self.name = full_name
       self.birthday = birthday

   def age(self):
      return self.birthday

   def fname(self):
       return _self.name

object = Color()
```

Comment: def age and def fname should be into class

Comment: This is not an answer, but it is relevant and you should read it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555970/5709499

Comment: I think this is also worth a read: [Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641219/2745495).

Comment: `return _self.name` ← this will raise an error. Did you mean `return self._name` instead?

Comment: This uses the term "properties", but the wording makes it sound like they mean "attributes". I'd suggest clarifying the assignment's intent; attributes are actual values stored in an instance, properties are accessors that are used like attributes, but invoke functions to satisfy them, rather than just looking up a value on the instance directly.

Comment: yes @TrebledJ self._name my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Using python `@property` getters and setters decorators, the calls to these from an instance are undistinguishable.
The inner workings follow the leading underscore convention for private attributes, without resorting to [double underscore name mangling](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python).

```
class Homework:

    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self._param1 = param1    # private attribute
        self.param2 = param2     # public attribute

    @property
    def param1(self):
        """accessor for private parameter
        """
        return self._param1

    @param1.setter
    def param1(self, value):
        """setter for private parameter
        """ 
        self._param1 = value

homework = Homework('The great secret', 'The public life of Napoleon')

# accessing the parameters follow the same syntax
print(homework.param1)
print(homework.param2)

# setting the parameters also follow the dotted syntax
homework.param1 = "you won't believe it"    
homework.param2 = 'but the dog ate it'    

print(homework.param1)
print(homework.param2)
```

Comment: Note: If they truly mean *private*, not just "non-public"/protected by convention, then it should be `self.__param1` (two underscores), not `self._param1` (one underscore). Single underscore means "protected" or "not part of public API", where double underscore employs name-mangling to separate the attribute name based on the class name.

Comment: Yes, agreed - if they truly mean private, then maybe python is not a good choice.