# Property decorator - How to protect private attribute?

Tags: python

I read tons of documents and answers and so far I haven't seen anything that is protecting python class attributes from being modified by clients.

This is one example:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self._legs = 4
    @property
    def legs(self):
        return self._legs

    @legs.setter
    def legs(self, n):
        self._legs = 4
```

No matter we have legs.setter method or not, users can always read or modify the Dog's attribute by _legs internal names. And they can even modify it's value by calling:

```py
dog = Dog()
dog._legs = 3

print(dog.legs)
# output 3
```

I don't really see how it protected things from being stolen or modified from client side?

Comment: You may wish to reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555932/public-or-private-attribute-in-python-what-is-the-best-way) which provides background on why this is the case in Python.

Comment: In all the reading you've done, did you happen upon the [first sentence here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Comment: "“Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python." @MarkMeyer, thanks for the link.

Comment: Python makes no attempt to secure parts of the program against attack from other parts of the program.

Comment: @metatoaster, thanks for sharing. That discussion is helpful.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, sad to realize that. Can imagine lot of hack around when calling a server program.

Comment: @TonyYun: Attempting to secure the program against itself just doesn't make sense in most threat models, and even in threat models where it does make sense, `private` is woefully insufficient for that.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica