# Attributes from superclass constructor in Python 3 on created or accessible?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/amentis/Dropbox/Rexi/index.py", line 21, in application
ui = Console.Console()
File "/home/amentis/Dropbox/Rexi/UI/Console.py", line 9, in __init__
self.__window = Window.Window(self, 'consoleWindow')
File "/home/amentis/Dropbox/Rexi/RxAPI/RxGUI/Window.py", line 16, in __init__
self.__parent.add_child(self)
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute '_Window__parent'
```

Here is a portion of the Console class:

```
class Console(Screen.Screen):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("REXI Console")
        self.__window = Window.Window(self, 'consoleWindow')
```

Of the Window class:

```
class Window(RxGUIObject.RxGUIObject):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        RxGUIObject.RxGUIObject.__init__(self, name, parent)
        self.__body = ""
        self.__javascript = ""
        self.__css = ""
        self.__parent.add_child(self)
```

and the RxGUIObject:

```
class RxGUIObject(RxObject.RxObject):
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        RxObject.RxObject.__init__(self, name)
        self.__parent = parent
        self.__children = list
```

Is `Window.__parent` not created or not existent and why?

Answer (score 1):

You just stumbled on python's [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).
Every attribute that starts with a double underscore and ends with at most one trailing underscore, like your `__parent`, is renamed to `_ClassName__attributename`.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.__a = 1
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.__a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '__a'
>>> b._A__a
1
```

Why is this done? In order to prevent attributes clashes when subclassing.
In particular the documentation states:

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely **to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses**), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any
>   identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

Note: name mangling does **not** mean an attribute is private. If you want to make an attribute "private" the convention is to use *one* underscore: e.g. `_parent`.
If you know that your class will be subclassed (often), then it *may* be a good idea to use name mangling to avoid name clashes.

Refer to [Python name mangling: When in doubt, do what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling-when-in-doubt-do-what) to decide whether to use it or not, however in general you should *not* use it.

Also note that, if subclasses *must* have access to `__parent` then you *definitely* should **not** use name mangling, since its very aim is to *avoid* subclasses accessing the attribute. In such cases simply use a public attribute and *document it*.
In alternative you can use a private attribute with name mangling and a property/some method to access it as hidden internal state, however for simple cases this is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

`__parent` is private property of `RxGUIObject`

> __double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes *FooBar*_boo; see below).

because of this your `__parent` property of `RxGUIObject` will be considered as `_RxGUIObject__parent`

To avoid this please define it explicetely

```
def __init__(self, parent, name):
    RxGUIObject.RxGUIObject.__init__(self, name, parent)
    self.__body = ""
    self.__javascript = ""
    self.__css = ""
    self.__parent = parent
    self.__parent.add_child(self)
```