# python pickle dump and load private variables

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, private-members

I need to protect a class variable. But what to do if the class supports save and load options?

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
class data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = range(100)

    @property    
    def a(self):
         return self.__a

    def save(self, path):
        pickle.dump(self,open(path, 'wb'), protocol=2)

    def load(self, path):
        obj = pickle.load(open(path, 'wb'))
        self.__a = obj.a
```

This is simple but `__a`attribute is no more protected because calling `instance.a` returns the exact `instance.__a` list and it can changed from the outside which is dangerous in my case.

is there any way around this?

Comment: in python there is no protection. You always can change `__a` even from outside.

Comment: what has the property todo with the save/load?

Comment: yes but you don't have any access to it. try instance.__a and you get rejected with an AttributeError

Comment: try `_data__a` and you have access to `__a`.

Comment: @Cobry: It is mangled to help separate the namespace from subclasses. It's there as `instance._data__a`.

Comment: obviously you need to load the save object attributes.
and you cannot do self = obj and its not safe to do self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__

Comment: @Cobry: [Python name mangling: When in doubt, do what?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7456807)

Comment: so, when it is dangerous to change `a`, then simply don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

To protect lists from being changed, you can return a copy of the list by your property:

```
@property
def a(self):
    return list(self.__a)
```

Comment: this is a copy and i'm dealing with huge data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of non-standard save/load methods, stick with the standard pythonic way of pickling objects, i.e. using pickle.dump and pickle.load directly.

The data members will be *as protected* after loading as they were before dumping, i.e. your object behaves the same.

```
class data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = range(100)
    @property    
    def a(self):
         return self.__a

obj = data()
# when you want to save, do:
x = pickle.dumps(obj)
# and for loading, do:
obj = pickle.loads(x)
obj.__dict__
=> {'_data__a': [0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  ...
]}
```

This approach has many advantages, e.g. you can safely pickle objects which reference instances of your class `data`.