# Use of __getattr__ in Python

Tags: python, oop, coding-style, getattr

How frequently should you use `__getattr__` in Python, rather than normal methods?

Which of these would be considered better?

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        if attribute == "spam":
            return self._spam * 100
        elif attribute == "eggs":
            return "fried" + self._eggs
        raise AttributeError
```

or

```
class B:
    def get_spam(self):
        return self._spam * 100

    def get_eggs(self):
        return "fried" + self._eggs
```

Comment: I will use @property for this.

Comment: Yes, that sounds perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `__getattr__` or accessor methods, use the [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class B(object):
    @property
    def spam(self):
        return self._spam * 100

    @property
    def eggs(self):
        return "fried" + self._eggs
```

Use `__getattr__` only to support *dynamic* attributes, where the number and names of the attributes are not known at class definition time.

Comment: Why `@property` and not accessor methods?

Comment: @Reloader: why use an accessor method when attribute access is cleaner? If an attribute makes sense from an API perspective (it naturally behaves like an attribute, doesn't take arguments and has a dynamic nature), why have the end user of your object explicitly call to get the value?

Comment: I don't know :) I'm trying to learn programming and Python, and that's why I'm asking. Just seeing that yours and OP's `classB` is nearly the same, except you have decorator implemented, but functionality is the same.

Comment: @Reloader The functionality isn't the same. I would do `a_B.get_spam()`, this would do `a_B.spam` (no function call).

Comment: Do all getter and setter methods should be decorated?

Comment: @Reloader: it is more Pythonic to use attributes. If you need a dynamic attribute, provide one by using `property`. The easiest way to use `property` is as a decorator.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! If I understand clearly, `property`'s only usage is to make accessor methods _callable_? What you mean by 'dynamic attribute'?

Comment: @Reloader: An attribute whose value depends on other factors or state; something that requires calculation, usually.

Comment: Do accessor methods and/or `property` should be used only with protected or private attributes? Is there advantage of using this methods in comparation to direct access to attributes (instance.attribute), if they are public? I've seen the code where getter and setter methods are defined although attributes are public, and that's confusing me. Thanks.

Comment: @Reloader: There are no private or protected attributes in Python. *All* attributes are public. Underscores are only a naming convention.

Comment: @Reloader: last comment here, this is not a chat room after all: [Python name mangling: When in doubt, do what?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7456807)