# Avoiding overriding of superclass variables. Mangling or alternatives

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a **large program** with multiple classes.

```
class Dog(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = 10

    def print_dog_food(self):
        print(self.food)


class Cat(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = 5

    def print_cat_food(self):
        print(self.food)
```

They are inherited by other classes:

```
class AllAnimals(Cat, Dog):
    def __init__(self):
        Cat.__init__(self)
        Dog.__init__(self)
```

Some variables will be having similar names. I am afraid of accidentally overriding an existing variable and creating nasty bugs:

```
# Wrong result. 
AllAnimals().print_cat_food()  # prints 10
AllAnimals().print_dog_food()  # prints 10
```

Keeping track of all those variables to avoid accidents seems impractical, so I was thinking of using mangling:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__food = ......
```

and get what i expect:

```
# Correct result.
AllAnimals().print_cat_food()  # prints 5
AllAnimals().print_dog_food()  # prints 10
```

---

[Mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900/4230591) solves my problem, but reading this [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456865/4230591) stating that:

> If you want to use it eventually, you can, but it is neither usual nor
>   recommended.

and the "This is culture" section of that answer makes me sceptical.

**Questions**:
 - Should I use mangling as in the example?
 - If not, what are my alternatives to avoid accidental overriding of variables?

Comment: `Cat` and `Dog` should inherit from a class `Animal`, not the other way around.

Comment: @chepner Why? (i was simply trying to create a simple example of a class inheriting from 2 others)

Comment: @user5061 because [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (subtyping, more specifically) is generally used to establish an `is-a` relationship. `Car` is a (special type of) `Vehicle`. `Teacher` is a `Person`. -> `Subclass` is special type of `Superclass`.

Comment: And specific to this example, an `Animal` is not a type of `Dog`; a `Dog` is a type of `Animal`.

Comment: @LukasGraf I did not pick correct names for my classes I guess. I ll edit tomorrow with more suitable names.

Comment: I had posted the answer you linked. Sorry if my answer caused confusion - it was a poor choice of words! In fact, your use case exactly the one which would be perfectly solved with double underscores. Use them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mangling to produce 'private' attributes is neither usual nor recommended, because there is no such thing as truly private attributes in Python.

Using mangling for what it was *designed to do*, reduce the likelyhood of subclasses clashing on attribute names, is absolutely pythonic and fine.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form **to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes**.

*Emphasis mine.*

However, the use-case is pretty rare; there are not many situations where you want the attribute to not be accidentally overridden. But if you *are* building base classes that are going to be widely subclassed (in a large project or as part of a framework or library intended for a wide range of uses), then using double-underscore names for implementation details is perfectly fine.

Comment: I didn't know this is what mangling was created for. So the linked post discourages mangling only when used to hide everything for no real reason?

Comment: @user5061: that's my take on it, yes.

Comment: _"..use-case is pretty rare.."_- Isn't a large program with (some) similar names one of those cases? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @user5061: the Python standard library reserves the use for classes that are expected to be widely subclassed and where 3rd parties should not need to know the internal implementation. The `__name` convention then is used in situations you want to support arbitrary subclassing where altering the base class is not feasible. If you have a large project being developed by multiple teams of developers then using the convention is a good use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual, because what you're doing here is unusual. However, given your requirements, I would say that using name-mangled variables is a perfectly appropriate thing to do.

Comment: What makes it unusual?