# hasattr keeps returning False

Tags: python, hasattr

```
class Avatar:

    def __init__(self, HP=100, damage=10, defends=10, magic=5):
        self.__hp = HP
        self.__dam = damage
        self.__def = defends
        self.__mag = magic

    def check_hasattr(self):
        print hasattr(Avatar,'__hp')

warrior = Avatar(99,9,9,4)
Avatar.check_hasattr(warrior)
```

Does somebody know why the `print` statement returns `False` while I expect `True`?

Comment: if I remove the underscores, it still returns False

Comment: That should be `hasattr(self, ...)` - then either `'_Avatar__hp'` or `'hp'` (depending on how you set up your instance) works fine. Also, why use `Avatar.check_hasattr(warrior)` rather than `warrior.check_hasattr()`?

Answer (score 8):

You have two problems:

1. Double underscore attribute names invoke *"name mangling"*, so e.g. `__hp` becomes `_Avatar__hp` (see e.g. [the style guide on inheritance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance)).
2. In `check_hasattr` you check for the attribute on `Avatar`, *the class*, rather than `self`, *the instance*.

This would work:

```
class Avatar:

    def __init__(self, HP=100, damage=10, defends=10, magic=5):
        self.__hp = HP
        self.__dam = damage
        self.__def = defends
        self.__mag = magic

    def check_hasattr(self):
        print hasattr(self, '_Avatar__hp')
```

However, there is no need to protect access to these attributes (and if there was, you should use a `@property` rather than name mangling); see e.g. [Python name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456807/3001761)

Note also that `Class.method(instance)` can be rewritten as `instance.method()`. In this case, though, the simplest approach would be to remove the method altogether and just call `hasattr(warrior, '_Avatar__hp')`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you are checking that the class `Avatar` has the attribute `__hp`, which it does not have it, only instances have it, since that attribute is defined in `__init__`. In other words, the `hasattr` should be called on the `self` or `avatar` object, not on the `Avatar` class.

Moreover, double underscores have a special meaning in python, it mangles the name so that is "private" in the sense that cannot be accessed directly. This means that checking that the instance has the attribute `__hp` will not work (you should check `_Avatar__hp` instead)

I changed your code to simplify and remove things that do not make too much sense:

```
class Avatar:
    def __init__(self,HP=100):
        self._hp = HP

>>> avatar = Avatar()
>>> hasattr(avatar, '_hp')
True
```

Note: if you create an instance of Avatar `avatar = Avatar()`, you should be calling the methods directly on the object `avatar.mymethod()`, and not `Avatar.mymethod(avatar)`

Comment: Downvoting is fine, but at least leave a message when you do so.