# What is the difference between Python's __add__ and __concat__?

Tags: python, operators

The list of Python's standard operators includes both `__add__(a, b)` and `__concat__(a, b)`. Both of them are usually invoked by `a + b`. My question is, what is the difference between them? Is there a scenario where one would be used rather than the other? Is there any reason you would define both on a single object?

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) I found the methods mentioned in.

Edit: Adding to the weirdness is this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types):

> Finally, sequence types should implement addition (meaning concatenation) and multiplication (meaning repetition) by defining the methods `__add__()`, `__radd__()`, `__iadd__()`, `__mul__()`, `__rmul__()` and `__imul__()` described below; they should not define `__coerce__()` or other numerical operators.

Comment: Well according to the documentation you linked to one is for numbers and one is for sequences

Comment: Note that `__concat__` isn't a *"magic method"* like `__add__` is: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: *Is* there a difference, except for the name?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - What makes you say that one is a "magic method" and the other isn't? Is that even an official term - I thought it was just a term people made up because it's a lot easier to say the words "magic <method>" when referring to them in a verbal conversation than "underscore underscore <method> underscore underscore". Also, looking at the docs you linked to, I found a quote that makes this even more confusing. I edited my question to include it.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare *magic method* refers to the `__foo__` double-underscore-both-sides methods that *implement actual class behaviour* - for example `a + b` is resolved to `a.__add__(b)`. Why is that quote confusing you? It's just telling you that `__add__` for two sequences should generally join them end-to-end.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The “magic methods” are officially called [“special methods”](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) and refer to methods which you can implement for types to provide built-in functionality for operators and other syntax features. Double-underscore methods in general are otherwise just subject to [name-mangling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling-when-in-doubt-do-what) and as such is sometimes used for private members.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Okay, so the important part is that `__concat__` isn't actually defined on any objects - that's why you say it isn't a magic method. If you post an answer laying out the fact that my confusion mostly stems from the `operator` module using method names that are identical to the names of magic methods, then I'll accept that.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I expanded a bit more in my answer on the `operator.add` vs. the special method `__add__`, hope it clears everything up :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you check the source for the `operator` module ([add](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/af793c7580f1/Lib/operator.py#l75), [concat](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/af793c7580f1/Lib/operator.py#l146)), you will find these definitions for those functions:

```
def add(a, b):
    "Same as a + b."
    return a + b

def concat(a, b):
    "Same as a + b, for a and b sequences."
    if not hasattr(a, '__getitem__'):
        msg = "'%s' object can't be concatenated" % type(a).__name__
        raise TypeError(msg)
    return a + b
```

So there is actually no difference except that `concat` actually requires a sequence type. Both functions use the `+` operator which effect depends on the types you add.

In general, using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) is not that useful most of the time. The module is mostly used when you need to pass a function that performs an operation, for example to functional functions like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), or [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). But usually, you can just use the `+` operator directly.

As for the underscore functions (`__add__` and `__concat__`), these are [just aliases](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/af793c7580f1/Lib/operator.py#l418):

```
__add__ = add
__concat__ = concat
```

But those are of course not related to the [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) used to overload operators for custom types. They are functions that match the same name as those special methods, probably to make them appear similar. Note that there is no special `__concat__` method on objects though.

Implementing `__add__` on a custom type will however affect how the operator module functions work, for example:

```
>>> class Example:
        def __init__ (self, x):
            self.x = x
        def __repr__ (self):
            return 'Example({})'.format(self.x)
        def __add__ (self, other):
            return Example(self.x + other.x)

>>> a = Example(2)
>>> b = Example(4)
>>> operator.add(a, b)
Example(6)
>>> a + b
Example(6)
```

As you can see, `operator.add` will use the implementation of the special method `Example.__add__`; but the reason for that is that the implementation of `operator.add` just uses the `+` operator (which behavior is explicitely defined by the special `__add__` method).

Comment: well, `operator` module is useful for passing the operator to `reduce()`

Comment: @mescalinum That’s what I wrote: *“The module is mostly used when you need to pass a function that performs an operation.”*

Comment: ok. I just liked to mention `reduce()` because functional programming is so cool :)

Comment: @mescalinum I added some functional examples, just for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

- `operator.__add__(a, b)`: Return `a + b`, for `a` and `b` **numbers** *.
- `operator.__concat__(a, b)`: Return `a + b` for `a` and `b` **sequences**.

What's the difference?

For example, you can't concatenate integers:

```
>>> operator.__concat__(2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object can't be concatenated
```

---

- actually `__add__(a, b)` just does `a + b`, hence it works on sequences too.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs,

> `operator.__add__(a, b)` Return a + b, for a and b numbers.
>
> `operator.__concat__(a, b)` Return a + b for a and b sequences.

**operator.__add__(a, b):**

It will just try to perform `a + b` and give the result.

**Eg.**

```
operator.__add__(1,2)  # performs 1 + 2
3

operator.__add__('a','b') # performs 'a'+'b'
'ab'
```

**operator.__concat__(a, b):**

Here, it will check if `a` has attribute `__getitem__`. If it does not have `__getitem__` attribute it raises an exception otherwise then try to perform `a + b`.

**Eg.**

On performing this operations on numbers, it will raise an exception.

```
operator.__concat__(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError:'int' object can't be concatenated
```

When performed on two strings, it perform string concatenation.

```
operator.__concat__('a','b')
'ab'
```

Comment: Does the behavior *actually* differ/limit? `operator.add("a","b")` produces the expected result (`"a"+"b"=>"ab"`) and the documentation says that the both "Return a + b".

Comment: Note that OP was talking about the `operator` modules, not special methods. Also note that there is no special `__concat__` method.