# __getattribute__() method for private attributes

Tags: python, class

In a class like this:

```
    class F(object):
        def __init__(self, x=0):
             self.__x = x

        def X(self):
            return self.__getattribute___('__x')
```

Is it possible to use `__getattribute__` for getting private attributes? Doing such Python 3 says `F has no attribute '__x'`. If my class is like this instead:

```
      class F(object):
          def __init__(self, x=0):
               self.x = x

          @property
          def x(self):
              return self.__x

          def X(self):
              return self.__getattribute__('x')
```

`__getattribute__` does work. I know private attributes aren't accessible outside of the class; does the first case not work because of something related to that?

Comment: Try `'_F__x'` - using leading double underscores invokes name mangling, don't use it for *"privacy"*.

Comment: Why are you using `__getattribute__` anyway instead of `getattr`?

Comment: Or, for that matter, just `return self.__x`, which *would* be unmangled correctly. I'd recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/7456807/3001761.