# Python - Defining an Objects Return Value

Tags: python, class, object, types, return

I am trying to implement a very basic Java-like Dimension-Class in Python:

```
class Dimension(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.__width
    @property
    def height(self):
        return self.__height
d = Dimension(800, 400)

print d.width
print d.height
```

This works fine: d.width returns an int=800, d.height returns an int=400.
But how do I define, that d should return a tuple=(800,400) instead of
`<__main__.Dimension object at 0xXXXXXXXX>`?

Is there an in-built class function similar to `__repr__` for it?
How do I define the returned value of a custom class?
Or do I have to implement a new type?

Thank you

Comment: You can make `__init__` return a tuple `width, height` but I guess that's not what you want, since you can't use all the instance methods then. If you want to implement conversion to a tuple then you should implement the `__iter__` method: `return (self.width, self.height)`.

Comment: `d` doesn't *return* anything; that is what it *is*.  (Try the same thing with a function.)  Methods & functions return values when called; you don't call a class.  If you want a method to call to get this type of value, add it to your class.

Comment: @ a_guest I don't know what you expect that to do, but `__init__` **must** return `None`, or you'll get `TypeError` when you try to create an instance of the class. For your example, you'd get `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'tuple'`.

Comment: BTW, `@property` should only be used when you need to evaluate some expression. Don't use it when a simple attribute lookup will suffice. Python isn't Java. Only create getters or setters when you really need them.

Comment: On a similar note, don't use leading double-underscore names like `.__width` unless you really need to invoke Python's name-mangling machinery. If you need private attributes (which you probably don't in this case), use a single leading underscore. And if you need to ask if you need Python's name-mangling machinery in a particular case, you probably don't. ;)

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456865/7430966 Thank you for mentioning it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that i can think of to what you described is using `namedtuples`

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: Dimension = namedtuple("Dimension", ('width', 'height'))

In [4]: d = Dimension(800, 400)

In [5]: d.width
Out[5]: 800

In [6]: d.height
Out[6]: 400

In [7]: d
Out[7]: Dimension(width=800, height=400)

In [8]: tuple(d)
Out[8]: (800, 400)

In [11]: w, h = d

In [12]: w, h
Out[12]: (800, 400)
```

Does this work for you? You could find more info about `namedtuples` here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Isn't it possible to work around the "tuple(d)" part?

Comment: You can use it like a regular tuple (see `w, h = d` part), if you could tell me where do you want to use this, maybe i can help you more.

Comment: Actually I asked without testing. I assumed that d[0] wound not work, which was wrong. Works perfectly fine. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you want your class to behave as a tuple, inherit from tuple:

```
class Dimension(tuple):
```

then override the `__new__` method to manipulate the creation:

```
def __new__(cls, width, height):
    tuple.__new__(cls, (width, height))
```

Leaving you with:

```
class Dimension(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, width, height):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (width, height)) # create tuple with 2 items

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.width = args[0] # width is the first argument passed
        self.height = args[1] # height is the next
```

---

```
>>> d = Dimension(800, 400)
>>> print(d)
(800, 400)
>>> print(d.width)
800
>>> print(d.height)
400
```

Comment: I thought inheriting from tuple would be a nice idea, so I suggested it... but now its looks like an overkill and some black magic :) Nevertheless, this solution is quite nice, depending on the use case

Comment: I agree, it's exactly what I searched for, but it looks really unconventional. Second opinion on this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing `__iter__` for conversion to `tuple`:

```
class Dimension:
    # Other code goes here.

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.width, self.height])
```

Note that I made `width` and `height` direct attributes of `Dimension` instead of using `@property`.

Example:

```
>>> d = Dimension(1, 2)
>>> tuple(d)
(1, 2)
```