# Python method name and variable name relation

Tags: python

I am reading python [tutorial](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html).

What relation does variable name `pinA` has with method name `getPinA()` , is it similar to automated getter setter in scala.

```
class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)

        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None

    def getPinA(self):
        return int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+ self.getLabel()+"-->"))

    def getPinB(self):
        return int(input("Enter Pin B input for gate "+ self.getLabel()+"-->"))
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Scroll down to the bottom and look at the full code.

Comment: Also, FWIW, Python guidelines suggest `naming_like_this` rather than `namingLikeThis`

Answer (score 0):

> is it similar to automated getter setter in scala.

Not really. `self.pinA = None` will set `pinA` to always be `None`. And any call to `getPinA()` will always use the `input()` function and never lookup the `self.pinA` value.

Python doesn't exactly have "encapsulation" like those JVM languages. In other words, you can always access attributes, so the concept of "getter & setter functions" isn't needed.

You can use `@property`, though, which acts like a way to implement a getter with an underlying value.

```
class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)
        self._pinA = None

    @property
    def pinA(self):
        if self._pinA is None:
            self._pinA = int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+ self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        return self._pinA
```

You can read more here about some [Python conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456865/2308683)