# Protected attributes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let's say I have this class in my module:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
```

So I have in my class a protected attribute called `_name` but I'm still able to call this attribute like this:

```
p = Person('Felipe')
print(p._name)
```

Why? Shouldn't protected attributes be protected from direct access outside their class or subclasses?

Comment: You're looking for `self.__name`.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm trying to understand WHY Python let me access protected attributes outside their class and subclasses like that

Comment: it's more about conventions, not prohibitions

Comment: Not sure what makes you think `self._name` is protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@coldspeed got it right.
You need a name which starts with a double underscore if you want Python apply the "mangling" to names: it basically changes the variable name and makes it not accessible from outside.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling) and this is the official python [doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

And don't forge this is Python, non Java.