# Parent class calls private attribute from child class

Tags: python, oop

In the following toy example, the last line B().show() doesn't call the appropriate version of show function. It's supposed to call the child version rather than the parent version. I guess I should do something like  __class_method() but couldn't figure out a complete answer.

I can certainly overwrite show function in B. But that essentially means to copy and paste show function. It's not elegant.

```
## version one ##
class A(object):

    def method(self):
        print("hello")

    def show(self):
        self.method()

class B(A):

    def method(self):
        print("goodbye")


A().show() ## print out hello
B().show() ## print out goodbye

## version two ##    
class A(object):

    def __method(self):
        print("hello")

    def show(self):
        self.__method()

class B(A):

    def __method(self):
        print("goodbye")


A().show() ## print out hello
B().show() ## print out hello
```

Comment: The problem here is that the method `A.show` cannot access the private `B.__method` and invokes `A.__method` instead. As suggested, you will have to overload the `show` as well.

Comment: What exactly is your purpose in using `__method` style names? I ask because there isn't really a "fix" to your issue other than "don't do that". You should almost never use name mangling, except for the rare situation where you have an internal variable in a proxy or mixin class that you don't want to accidentally collide with some unknown other class's variables.

Comment: @Blckknght First intention is trying to hide some attributes to users (e.g., users cannot see it through calling __dict__

Comment: @Blckknght Second intention is that A itself is inherited from an outside library. Since that library use double underscore to hide similar attributes, I think it favorable to inherit this convention too.

Comment: *I think it's favorable to inherit this convention* -- I disagree ([for the reasons here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling)).

Comment: And user *can* see it, you're just making it more difficult (e.g. see `dir(B)`).

Comment: @J.Lin I believe I have pretty clearly outlined your options in my answer, but the important things are that you should definitely not use `_class__method`, and if you are trying to do exactly this, _elegantly_, then the most elegant way is for `__method` to be public.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a method name with two underscores, it makes it accessible from only that class. Consider the following example:

```
class A():
    def __m(self):
        pass
    def m(self):
        print(self.__m)

A().m()  # <bound method A.__m of <__main__.A object at 0x10e0c1898>>
A().__m()  # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__m'
```

So what happened to `A().__m`? Check out `A.__dict__`, where attributes are looked up:

```
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '_A__m': <function A.__m at 0x10e0ab730>, 'm': <function A.m at 0x10e0ab7b8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

Most importantly:

```
'_A__m': <function A.__m at 0x10e0ab730>
```

So the function you wrote, `__m`, is renamed to `_A__m`. You are not meant to access these methods from anywhere outside of the class.

If you have a method `show` in your class that calls a method `__method` (that starts with a `__`), it will only ever call that method of that class because it will never know about `_B__method`, only about `_A__method`.

Note that you absolutely should never use `_A__method` to call this method from outside of the class. If you need to do what you are doing, you should use one underscore.

If you really need to have the `__method` method of `B` be private, then yes, `B` should override `show` as well:

```
class A(object):
    def __method(self):
        print("hello")
    def show(self):
        self.__method()

class B(A):
    def __method(self):
        print("goodbye")
    def show(self):
        self.__method()

A().show() ## print out hello
B().show() ## print out goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the private methods of each class, and be able to access them, you could do something like this:

```
class A(object):

    def __method(self):
        print("hello")
    method = __method

    def show(self):
        self.method()


class B(A):

    def __method(self):
        print("goodbye")
    method = __method
```

#### output:

```
hello
goodbye
```

Comment: This makes the private method public: `B().method()` prints `goodbye`.

Comment: Yes, it creates an alias for the private method; this alias is public. You cannot call the private method directly, therefore, you could (if it was useful), replace with `method = __blah`, `__blah` being some other private method of B, without breaking client code.

Comment: Why would you declare a method as private and then provide a way for it to be accessed from anywhere? How is this any different than just not declaring it private?

Comment: This is a good question @MoxieBall; I would not do this; however, there may be cases where you need to modify the behavior of your class without breaking client code, or subclasser's code, as alluded in my earlier comment.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I think that, if it is necessary to keep the `__method` convention for making methods private, the real solution is that every method that calls a `__method` must be overridden in B as well. I have just added this as an addendum to my answer