# Python: Change bound method to another method

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to learn about bound methods in python and have implemented the code below:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.__x=x
        self.__y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self.__x, self.__y)

def draw2(self):
    print("x",self.__x, "y", self.__y)

p1=Point(1,2)
p2=Point(3,4)
p1.draw()
p2.draw()
p1.draw=draw2
p1.draw(p1)
```

When I run this code, the following output is produced:

```
1 2
3 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    p1.draw(p1)
  File "main.py", line 10, in draw2
    print("x",self.__x, "y", self.__y)
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute '__x'
```

Why is it not possible for me to change p1.draw() after changing it so that it points at draw2?

Comment: What makes you say that you can't?

Comment: Probably name mangling by the way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, that's what you get for trying to enforce privacy in Python. ;)

Outside the body of the class, you must refer to the attributes `__x` and `__y` as `_Point__x` and `_Point__y` because of [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling).

If you change the two attributes to non-mangled names (e.g. `_x` and `_y`) or use the names `_Point__x` and `_Point__y` in `draw2`, your code won't throw an error.

In my opinion you should think thrice before using mangled names. Write proper docstrings, but don't restrict the user of your class in such an annoying manner. Using single underscore names is well understood as "don't touch this" in the community.

As you already seem to have noticed, `p1.draw` behaves differently after your monkey patch because `draw2` is not a bound method of the instance `p1`, so you need to pass `p1` explicitly as the argument. I suggest that you bind the instance `p1` to `draw2` by leveraging the function's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) before you reassign the name `draw`.

Putting everything together, the code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self._x=x
        self._y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self._x, self._y)

def draw2(self):
    print("x",self._x, "y", self._y)

p1 = Point(1,2)
p2 = Point(3,4)
p1.draw()
p2.draw()
p1.draw = draw2.__get__(p1)
p1.draw()
```

produces the output

```
1 2
3 4
x 1 y 2
```

where `draw2.__get__(p1)` produces a callable that behaves like `draw2`, but automatically passes `p1` as the first argument.

Comment: An alternative to draw2.__get__(p1) is to use explicit type declaration: `import types` `p1.draw = types.MethodType(draw2, p1)`. This explicitly instructs the instance p1 to now have a bound method which authomatically passes `self` as first argument

Answer (score 2):

Double underscores cause Python to ['mangle'](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) the name of the attribute. It will actually be stored as `_Point__x` instead of `__x`. If you change your function like this, it will work:

```
def draw2(self):
    print("x",self._Point__x, "y", self._Point__y)
```

The double underscores are supposed to indicate a variable that is private to the class and should not be accessed outside it. [Name mangling makes it more difficult to do so accidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private/70900).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `__x` that you have defined, as you see if you just:

```
p1=Point(1,2)
p1.__x
```

it says that `'Point' object has no attribute '__x'` again. and so this problem is not because of your draw function. it is for your attributes. so if you define your class like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self.x, self.y)

def draw2(self):
    print("x",self.x, "y", self.x)
```

this will work just fine.

additionally, if you go with your fist implementation, with `dir` function you can see that `__x` and `__y` is accessible like `_Point__x` and `_Point__y`. so you can also do this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.__x=x
        self.__y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self.__x, self.__y)

def draw2(self):
    print("x",self._Point__x, "y", self._Point__y)
```

> Note that using `__` is to define a private attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with your code.

1. Using double-underscore fields, causing their name to be "mangled". In other words, when you specify field `__x` in class `Point` its name is actually `_Point__x`. The point is to enable accessing this field only from within the same class (and then it will work). You have 2 options fixing that - access this field from outside using `__Point_x` or simply rename it to a single-underscore field (`_x`).
2. Your re-bounding is wrong. You should replace it on the class and not the specific object. The way you are doing it now, you have to invoke explicitly passing `self`:  `p1.draw(p1)`. If however you would do:

   ```
   Point.draw = draw2
   p1.draw()  # works as expected
   ```

Comment: Note that point 2 here changes behaviour for all class instances, already instantiated and future instantiations. The solution to bind a method for just the specific instance can be seen below from e.g. @timgeb and my comment about using `MethodType` as an alternative.