# Can someone explain this behaviour of python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Below is a piece of code. I expect in the first print statement to print 456 but it is printing 123. Can anyone help with the explanation of this?

Have a look at the code below.

```
class employee():

    __private_var = 123
    phone_number=3274687

    def __init__(self, phone):
        self.phone_number = phone

# Private Functions

    def get_private_func(self):
        return self.__private_var

    def set_private_func(self):
        self.__private_var = 1

class VIP(employee):

    phone_number=123456
    __private_var = 456


obj1 = employee(1312321)
obj2 = VIP(1312321)
#Unable to reassign new value to private variable
print (obj2.get_private_func())

#Able to reassign new value to private variable
obj2.set_private_func()
print (obj2.get_private_func())

print (obj1.get_private_func())
```

Expected results:

```
456
1
123
```

Got these results:

```
123
1
123
```

Comment: Please simply the example. You don't need all these methods and abstractions. This whole question boils down to behavior of class attributes (namely those that start with `__`) in subclasses

Comment: [Python name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903236/6699447)

Answer (score 0):

Class variable `__private_var` should be initialised as `super(employee).__private_var` not `__private_var` in VIP class.

Another approach:

```
class VIP(employee):
    __private_var = 456

    def get_private_func(self):
        return self.__private_var
```

Comment: But why a VIP instance `get_private_func` did not access `__private_vaar` set on `VIP` class?

Comment: OK, but why is it not assigning the new value which is 456 in this case. Some explanation would be very helpful

Comment: Python cannot figure out if you are assigning a value to the variable in the super class or creating a new variable in child class. The default behaviour is to create a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a behavior of private vars(namely the ones with a name that starts with __), make it not private and it should work(works on my machine)