# How can I create an object that contains instances of a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I want to create an object that contains some instances of a class. That object should be some kind of list-generalization of the instances. E.g. I have the following class:

```
class car:
    def __init__(self, prize, color)
        self.prize = prize
        self.color = color
```

Now I want to have an object `cars` that contains many instances of the class car but that I can work with like an instance of car, i.e. `cars.prize` should return a list of the prizes for all the instances I collected in that object `cars`.

Comment: `def car():`? not `class car:`?

Comment: Have you tried implementing such a collection? What happened?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this

Comment: Have you considered making a `cars` list instead? Then you iterate over the list or use direct access to particular elements. The usage looks closer to real world. although you cannot do `cars.prices` to get all the prices without extra work.

Comment: That's not really a question. Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. If you want to know how to implement a container, look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small error in your code: you need a `:` at the end of your `__init__` method definition line:

`def __init__(self, prize, color):`

Here's an implementation of `cars` which does what you desire. The use of the `@property` decorator allows you to access methods as object properties:

```
class car:
    def __init__(self, prize, color):
        self.prize = prize
        self.color = color

class cars:
    def __init__(self, list_of_cars):
        for one_car in list_of_cars:
            assert isinstance(one_car, car) # ensure you are only given cars
        self.my_cars = list_of_cars

    @property
    def prize(self):
        return [one_car.prize for one_car in self.my_cars]

    @property
    def color(self):
        return [one_car.color for one_car in self.my_cars]


>>> a = car('prize1', 'red')
>>> b = car('prize2', 'green')
>>> c = car('prize3', 'azure')
>>> carz = cars([a,b,c])
>>> carz.prize
['prize1', 'prize2', 'prize3']
>>> carz.color
['red', 'green', 'azure']
```

You can add more checking on inputs in each object if desired, but this is the basic framework. Hope it helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: So I guess there is no way that the new class `cars` inherits these properties from the class `car` as functions for the list?

Comment: Not really - it would inherit the initialization of a single prize and a single color from `car`, but that doesn't do what we want. As it stands, `cars` is a pretty thin wrapped for a list of cars, probably only really useful if you want to add more functionality (summing the costs of cars, finding the most popular color, etc)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like that:

```
class Cars:
    def __init__(self, list_of_cars):
        self.cars_list = list_of_cars
        self.prize = [car.prize for car in self.cars_list]
        self.color = [car.color for car in self.cars_list]
```

Let's see how it can be used:

```
list_of_cars = [Car(1000, "red"), Car(2000, "blue"), Car(3000, "Green")]
x = Cars(list_of_cars)

print(x.prize)
# [1000, 2000, 3000]

print(x.color)
#["red", "blue", "Green"]
```

Comment: This means the `prize` and `color` can get out-of-sync with `cars_list`, I'd look at properties or even `__getattr__` to redirect attribute access to the list

Comment: How can it get out-of-sync?? Could you give me an example?

Comment: `x.cars_list.append(Car(4000, "Purple"))`?

Comment: That's not how classes work. If you want to add value to the class, you create a method to do so.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. That *will* work. It violates the Law of Demeter, if that's what you mean? You could implement `append` and other list methods on `Cars` and name the property with the conventional `_` prefix to discourage direct access, but... you haven't. `x.color.append("Purple")` also works, for example.

Comment: Not exactly the "LoD"... Look, the basic concept behind encapsulation is to hide the implementation details. So, I can solve this issue by making `cars_list` private. It's simple! Also, I didn't add other methods like `append` or `remove` because that wasn't the question.

Comment: I am familiar with encapsulation, thank you. And yes there are various solutions (well you can't *really* make it private in Python, but there are conventions), but the point is you *haven't applied any of them* or even mentioned this as a thing the OP should consider. It leaves a big foot-gun with someone who is likely not aware of the implications. More broadly, maybe just don't drop implementation-only answers on low-effort questions.

Comment: Actually, I can make it private in python... here `self.__cars_list`. Now, it's private. Secondly, why should I create other methods the OP didn't ask about? Maybe he/she doesn't want it. Anyway, you can tell me what I should do and I will consider it for sure

Comment: That's [*name mangled*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456807/3001761), but sure.

Comment: I really really enjoyed this discussion. The last link was so informative. I know that was a waste of your time. But definitely it wasn't the same for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new `class car_list()` that holds a list of cars (to which you can append, remove etc). In that class, add a`get_prizes()` method that returns a list of prizes by iterating over the list. For example:

```
class car_list():
   def __init__(self, cars):
      self.cars = cars # This is a list

   def get_prizes(self):
      return [car.prize for car in self.cars]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by the wonderful Sam idea of using decorators. So please give him the point if you think you are pleased with this chunk of code.

```py
def singleton(all_cars):
    instances = {} # cars instances
    def get_instance():
        if all_cars not in instances:
            # all_cars is created once
            instances[all_cars] = all_cars()
        return instances[all_cars]
    return get_instance

@singleton
class all_cars:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {}

    @property
    def prizes(self):
        return [e.prize for e in self.inventory.values()]
    @property
    def colors(self):
        return [e.color for e in self.inventory.values()]        

class car:
    def __init__(self, prize, color):
        self.prize = prize
        self.color = color

    def register(self):
        # Like class all_cars is a singleton it is instantiate once, reason why dict is saved
        cars = all_cars()
        cars.inventory[len(cars.inventory)] = self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creating cars items
    car1 = car("50", "Blue")
    car2 = car("300", "Red")
    car3 = car("150", "Gray")
    # Register part for cars
    car1.register()
    car2.register()
    car3.register()
    # Like class all_cars is a singleton it is instantiate once, reason why dict is saved
    cars = all_cars()

    print(cars.inventory)
    """{0: <__main__.car object at 0x7f3dbc469400>, ---> This is object car1
    1: <__main__.car object at 0x7f3dbc469518>,  ---> This is object car2
    2: <__main__.car object at 0x7f3dbc469550>}  ---> This is object car3"""
    print(cars.prizes)
    """['50', '300', '150']"""
    print(cars.colors)
    """['Blue', 'Red', 'Gray']"""
```

Comment: This is inheritance... the OP didn't mean that

Comment: That doesn't really make sense in this context, a list of cars isn't a car, although it may share some of the same interface

Comment: I reviewed entirely the design based on Sam idea :-)