# Trying to use setter but i get a this error : @versionNum.setter AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setter'

Tags: python, oop, setter

```
class Mobile:
    def __init__(self,versionNum, isAndroid, memorysize):
        self.__versionNum = versionNum
        self.__isAndroid = isAndroid
        self.memorySize = memorysize
        self.__appArray = []
        self.used_memory = 0
    
    @versionNum.setter
    def versionNum(self, versionNum):
        self.__versionNum = versionNum
    
    @isAndroid.setter
    def isAndroid(self, bool):
        self.__isAndroid = bool
    
    @memorysize.setter
    def memorysize(self, size):
        self.__memorysize = size
```

*I use proprety setter to the version of Mobile but i get an error*

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. You can't have a setter without a getter
2. You probably want to avoid `__` as a prefix ([*why*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling))
3. `self.memorySize` is both an attribute and a property.
4. You probably want to avoid `bool` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in `bool`
5. PEP8 conventions say that attribute names should be camel-cased

See the below fixes.

```
class Mobile:
    def __init__(self, version_num, is_android, memory_size):
        self._version_num = version_num
        self._is_android = is_android
        self._memory_size = memory_size
        self._app_array = []
        self.used_memory = 0
    
    @property
    def version_num(self):
        return self._version_num
    
    @version_num.setter
    def version_num(self, version_num):
        self._version_num = version_num
    
    @property
    def is_android(self):
        return self._is_android
    
    @is_android.setter
    def is_android(self, is_android):
        self._is_android = is_android
    
    @property
    def memory_size(self):
        return self._memory_size
    
    @memory_size.setter
    def memory_size(self, size):
        self._memory_size = size
```

Comment: You can't have a setter without a *property*; you can have a property without a getter: e.g., `version_num = property(None, lambda s, v: setattr(s, '_version_num', v))`.