# Should I use _ or __ prefix in python for private attributes?

Tags: python, class, prefix

I and my friend debated which prefix is a **convention and the preferred way** to use when you create attributes to a class and want to tell that they are `private`.
We know there isn't a real `private` modifier in python, and in both prefixes, `_` and `__` every programmer will know how to get/set to the attributes anyway.

However, what will be the best way to tell others python programmers that the attribute is private? `_` or `__`?

Comment: There is no debate, it is a *single underscore*. Double-underscores are for *double-underscore name-mangling*.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling answer your question?

Comment: Double-underscore name-mangling is there to *prevent accidental name collisions in subclasses* for classes that are *meant to be subclassed*. Straight from PEP8: "Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed". See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance

Comment: Thank you all for the responses