# How to determine if a method was called from within the class where it's defined?

Tags: python, scope, encapsulation

I'm trying to implement an (admittedly *unPythonic*) way of encapsulating a lot of instance variables.

I have these variables' names mapped to the respective values inside a dictionary, so instead of writing a lot of boilerplate (i.e. `self.var = val`, like times 50), I'm iterating over the dictionary while calling `__setattr__()`, this way:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ("var1", "var2", "var3")
    def __init__(self, data):
        for k, v in data.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)
```

Then I would override `__setattr__()` in a way that controls access to these properties.
From within `__setattr__()`, I'd check if the object has the property first, in order to allow setattr calls inside `__init__()`:

```
def __setattr__(self, k, v):
    if k in self.__class__.__slots__:
        if hasattr(self, k):
            return print("Read-only property")
    super().__setattr__(k, v)
```

The problem is, I also need some of these properties to be writeable elsewhere in `myClass`, even if they were already initialized in `__init__()`. So I'm looking for some way to determine if setattr was called inside the class scope or outside of it, e.g.:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ("var",)
    def __init__(self):
        self.__setattr__("var", 0)
    def increase_val(self):
        self.var += 1  # THIS SHOULD BE ALLOWED

my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.var += 1  # THIS SHOULD BE FORBIDDEN
```

My pseudo definition would be like:

```
# pseudocode
def setattr:
    if attribute in slots and scope(setattr) != MyClass:
        return print("Read-only property")
    super().setattr
```

Also, I'd rather not store the entire dictionary in one instance variable, as I need properties to be immutable.

Comment: Looks like a rare case where [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling)  should be used, however keep in mind it will still allow to modify the variable from outside the class, it will just be a lot harder

Comment: Another alternative will be a property with frame inspection

Comment: @DeepSpace I find the inspection approach interesting actually, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question to share with anyone with the same issue.

Thanks to @DeepSpace in the comments I've delved a bit into the **frame inspection** topic which I totally ignored before.

Since the well known `inspect` library relies on **`sys._getframe()`** in some parts, namely the parts that I'm mainly interested in, I've decided to use `sys` instead.

The function returns the current **frame object** in the execution stack, which is equipped with some useful properties.

E.g., **`f_back`** allows you to locate the immediate outer frame, which in case  `__setattr__()` was called within the class, is the class itself.

On the outer frame, **`f_locals`** returns a dictionary with the variables in the frame's local scope and their respective values.

One can look for **`self`** inside `f_locals` to determine wether the context is a class, although it's a bit 'dirty' since any non-class context could have a `self` variable too.
However, if `self` is mapped to an object of type `MyClass`, then there shouldn't be ambiguities.

Here's my final definition of `__setattr__()`

```
def __setattr__(self, k, v):
    if k in self.__class__.__slots__:
        self_object = sys._getframe(1).f_back.f_locals.get("self")
        if self_object is None or self_object.__class__ != MyClass:
            return print(k, "is a read-only property")
    super().__setattr__(k, v)
```

As a conclusion, I feel like pursuing variable privacy in Python is kind of going against the tide; it's definitely a cleaner solution to label variables as 'protected' according to the recognized standard, without bothering too much about the actual accessibility.

Another side note is that frame inspection doesn't look like a very reliable approach for applications meant for production, but more like a debugging tool. As a matter of fact, some `inspect` functions do not work with some Python implementations, e.g. those lacking stack frame support.

Comment: What's with the `return print(...)` you keep using? It also seems like you could just check if `self_object == self`.

Comment: I use return `print()` just to immediately return the function after printing (since print returns None) and avoid falling into `super().__setattr__()`. I usually prefer returning when a certain 'stopping' conditions is met instead of having if-else blocks (just a coding style no reason behind it). As per self, if I use `self_object == self`, I'm potentially allowing subclasses that inherit the same `__setattr__` to change that attribute, while I don't want to. This I didn't clearly state in my question actually, but I want the class defining the function to be the only one able to do that.

Comment: Preventing inheritance makes sense, I suppose. As for the `return print()` rationale, seems like you really ought to be raising some kind of exception.

Comment: That I've beed told on another occasion too. Still I'm not getting why; I'm relatively new to Python, but isn't return supposed to accept a value or something that evaluates to some result? If that's the case, print() technically evaluates to None. While admittedly suffering from the patology of condensing code to unnecessary extents, I still find interesting to learn why something like this is bad practice.

Comment: IMO it a poor practice because you're executing the `print`  for a side-effect that would likely be unwelcome by most, but more importantly, that the failure to set the attribute is otherwise being ignored and program execution allowed to continue. Seems like not doing what as intended should raise an exception that will be fatal unless there's an `except` handler in place for it so the caller can deal with it happening in some other manner.