# Can't Access Inherited Attributes from a Parent class

Tags: python, class

```
class People:
    # parent to both Employee and Customer classes
    def __init__(self, id, name, ssn): # define class People
                                       # self used to accesses attributes and methods in class
    # set instance variable
        self.__id = id
        self.__name = name
        self.__ssn = ssn

class Employee(People):
    #Child of Class People
    def __init__(self, id, name, ssn, password):
        People.__init__(self, id, name,ssn)
        self.__password = password

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID :{self.__id}\nName :{self.__name}\nSSN :{self.__ssn}\nPassword :{self.__password}"
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you use double leading underscores for attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Naming variable with double underscore prefix (e.g. `__somename`) triggers python "name mangling". This is intended to prevent name collision, and as a result, Python requires a special attribute name to access: `_ClassName__somename`  instead of `__somename`.

For example:

```
class Person():
   def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

>>> Person("x").__name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '__name'
>>> Person("x")._Person__name
'x'
```

To fix this you should either use the "mangled" name to access, or rename your variables to remove the double underscore.

For more details see this [detailed stackoverflow post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling) .

Comment: There is no such thing as "private" in python. Don't confuse name mangling with private. A single leading undescore means "should be private" by convention. Name mangling is a way to prevent name colisions.

Comment: Although it's actually not private,  people do use `__` to "hide" or make their variables "slightly more private" or harder to access. If you search "python make variable private" you will find a lot of content suggesting "__name" as a solution. But it's a fair point that this is confusing. I revised the text to clarify

Comment: And, from a style point of view, should use `super()` instead of invoking `People.__init__()`