# Private properties in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. Here is some test code:

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self,num,option):
    self.__num = num
    self.option = option
  def getNum(self):
    return self.__num
  def getOption(self):
     return self.option
  
   


my_num = Test(77,1)
print(my_num.getNum())    // 77
print(my_num._Test__num)  // 77
print(my_num.__num)       // Attribute error
```

My question is:

Why `my_num.getNum()` returns 77?

Why `self.__num` through `getNum` has value and `my_num.__num` returns error?

`self` in `self.__num` points to `my_num`, isn't it? Since `__num` is a private property, how is it accessible through `self` whereas `self` points to an **object**?

Comment: In Python comments start with `#`

Comment: It's called name mangling. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: Some more info here too: [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: "Why my_num.getNum() returns 77?" What do you think it should return instead? Why? "Since __num is a private property, how is it accessible through self whereas self points to an object?" I don't understand the objection. Properties belong to objects. `getNum` is a *method of the class*, so of course it can directly access attributes by their actual name.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you're passing value 77, which gets assigned to `self.__num`.  Later when you request `.getNum()` it's simply passing the same `self.__num` back to you, so you get 77 back.  The best way to think of `self` is like `this` in other languages, it's referencing the instantiated object itself.

You get an error on calling `.__num` directly because of name mangling, instead it's been renamed to `._Test__num`.

What you're encountering is something called [name mangling](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python).

Specifically:

> A double underscore prefix causes the Python interpreter to rewrite the attribute name in order to avoid naming conflicts in subclasses.

That is why you are able to reference `._Test__num` and not `.__num`.  There's a StackOverflow question with more in-depth answers here:  [Python name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling)

Comment: Name mangling was not my issue/question. What I cannot understand is how `self.__num` inside `getNum` method returns 77 since `self` points to `my_num` object and `my_num` does not have ` __num` property...

Comment: Answer edited to include the self bit.  The latter part of the question is related to name mangling.