# Importing class with leading double underscores in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, class

I'm trying to unit test my private class, but import doesn't seem to find my class:

```
class __MyClass:
     something

from location import __MyClass

class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
          self.test_class = __MyClass(x, y, z)
```

I've also tried using the entire reference, but it's still unable to find my class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "private" class. Using double-underscores in a class name would be very unusual (note, that never makes something "private" because python doesn't have access modifiers). In any case, what "doesn't work" **exactly**?

Comment: Note, using an identifier with double leading underscores (and without trailing leading underscores) *anywhere* in a class definition leads to *name mangling*. If you want to avoid that, simply use a single underscore in your class name.

Comment: A reference for further details on name-mangling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/python-name-mangling