Prevent a class variable from being modified outside the class
I have the following class where I have defined couple of class variables and a helper class method where I am updating the value of these class variables based on some condition.
class Foo:
    _UPDATED_AT: datetime = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    STATUS: bool = False


    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        # updated the class variable from here only based on some condition
        if some_cond:
            cls.STATUS = True 
            cls.UPDATED_AT = datetime.datetime.now()

        return cls.STATUS

I want to 1) prevent these class variables from being updated(i.e. being set) directly outside of the class, 2) but to be able to update the classvar from the class method, so semantically something behaving like a private class variable in C++.
I was able to achieve the first of the two requirements by using the a metaclass which basically blocks the attributing setting
class MyMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, key, value):
        raise AttributeError(f"Can't set {cls}.{key}")

However as expected this also prevents updates from happening within the class. I am not sure if this is possible to achieve with pure python but basically I guess somehow I need to detect if the update is happening from inside or outside of the class.
I know we can mark the variables as private in Python with a leading underscore(I already have one in my class) that can tell consumers of your code that these are variables meant for internal use and are not supposed to be used directly by the consumer.
However I am just interested out of curiosity if this is somehow achievable ?

You cannot and you should not, python does not work that way. We are all consenting adults here. The best you should do is to mark private variables with a leading underscore. If user of your code refuses to follow your guidance and deliberately modifies what should not be modified, resulting in his broken code, it is his fault.

You can set attributes like STATUS with e. g. type.__setattr__(Foo, 'STATUS', True) but this can be done everywhere.

@Jeyekomon I totally agree with you here but out of curiosity I am interested if this is achievable ?

Would type hinting the variable as final work ?

@rasjani No. The type hints are just suggestions, not enforcements.

@rasjani No they can't, they have no runtime implication at your code. It isn't lot different from marking your variable as private by prefixing it with an underscore.

The short answer is no.  You cannot do that.  If a variable is accessible by the code, it is accessible by the user.
If you are determined to make your code difficult for someone to use there are obfuscation methods that do that such as using unicode characters in the name: _ՍPDATED_AT

@rohit Sure, runtime  checking should have been obvious. Point was more about  if the code aint library or shipped to 3rd parties, mypy should still fail if that class variable is changed..

You can use __ to name mangle the property - it can still be changed if access under the mangled name, but it'll be "hidden": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456807/should-i-use-name-mangling-in-python - you can also use the getter/setter property wrappers, but there's always a way around if  you really want to.

@MatsLindh If I am not mistaken the name mangling thing with __ helps when you want to access Parent class's version of variable from subclass. The property won't work here because a property is a descriptor object defined at class level and you can always override with any value. The setter constraint of property is applicable only when you access it with instance.

@MatsLindh Oh now I get what you mean when you referred to name mangling.. for sure it can obfuscate the the variable name but it still can't enforce anything

You could use the @property decorator with getters and setters backed by the field you don't want to get accessed from outside the class. But there's no way to actually enforce users cannot access it from outside. Using a leading underscore and property setters can only go so far, since Python does not have a concept of "private" variables.

"We are all consenting adults here" is a good guide to sane behaviour. That being said, the next best (sane) thing is to just use two underscores. That way private name mangling will kick in.
This doesn't keep anyone out that really tries to break your invariants, but python just isn't the language for that.
Another way to work around the issues with what you're doing now could be to call super().__setattr__, but that seems moderately insane to me.
