# How to restrict users from creating a python object?

Tags: python

I have a domain object `User`. I am looking for some way to restrict other python classes form creating any objects of `user' type.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a singleton User object? Singleton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: There is always a way. Write it in the docs.

Comment: No, not singleton. But The object should be created by some global method in the module only. If possible, I have very little knowledge about Python

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closures to hide the object away from the code but please accept that *doing it in Python is considered very unpythonic and is pretty much against the philosophy of the language*. You are supposed to document proper behavior, not guard against your users.

```
class KittenFactory(object):
    def __create_teh_secret_objectz(self):
        class Kitten(object):
            i_can_haz_invisible = True
        return Kitten()
```

Willing programmers will still be able to either `copy()` it or get its `type()` and instantiate it manually.

In other words: don't go there.