# Constrain method access to an interface?

Tags: python, interface, abstract-class

I have a Python system consisting of around 9-10 classes all implementing most of a fat duck-typed interface and used interchangeably by a large collection of modules.  I'm trying to refactor the classes into a core, explicit (i.e. ABC) interface and peripheral functionality, following separation of responsibility, but in order to do that I need to be able to tell when the consumer modules are calling methods outside the core interface.

Suppose I have an ABC with abstract methods:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyABC:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod 
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

I also have a class implementing those abstract methods as well as other methods:

```
class MyClass(MyABC):
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def bar(self):
        pass

instance = MyClass()

>>> isinstance(instance, MyABC)
True
```

How can I ensure that when I pass `instance` to a method `do_something` it *only* uses the methods that are part of `MyABC` (in this case `foo`) and not any other methods (`bar`)?  In a static-typed language (e.g. C++) I could pass `do_something` a pointer of the ABC type; is there some sort of wrapper available in Python that will restrict method access similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
class ABCGuard(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, *abcs):
        if any(not isinstance(obj, abc) for abc in abcs):
            raise ValueError("{0} must implement {1}"
                             .format(obj.__class__.__name__,
                                     ', '.join(abc.__name__ for abc in abcs
                                               if not isinstance(obj, abc))))
        self.__obj = obj
        self.__abcs = abcs
        classname = '{0}{{{1}}}'.format(obj.__class__.__name__,
                                        ', '.join(abc.__name__ for abc in abcs))
        self.__class__ = type(classname, (ABCGuard, ) + abcs, {})

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('_ABCGuard__') or (name.startswith('__') and
                                              name.endswith('__')):
            return super(ABCGuard, self).__getattribute__(name)
        elif any(name in abc.__abstractmethods__ for abc in self.__abcs):
            return getattr(self.__obj, name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                                 (self.__class__.__name__, name))

    def __dir__(self):
        return [x for abc in self.__abcs for x in abc.__abstractmethods__]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple answer: no

There is no concept of private methods/variables in Python that would be enforced, as described here in [detail](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

In Python this is handeld by [convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

And if you really want to go into the deep internals checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private).