# Why does a specific import sees other imports? Python 2.6

Tags: python

I have two files. SysDump.py which does `from libApi import _SysDump` and in the other file libApi.py I have many classes and one of them is

```
class _SysDump():
    import cPickle as _cPickle
    import math as _math
    from zipfile import ZipFile as _ZipFile
    import re as _re
```

the problem is the import in SysDump not only sees the _SysDump in libApi.py but other classes too!! How can I prevent it from seeing inside the other classes?

Python 2.6. Yes I do have a `__init__.py`. Can it in any way help bring the privacy I am hoping for?

Comment: Doesn't "pulling up" the imports out of the class do the trick?

Comment: What do you mean, it "sees" the other classes?  You've only imported `_SysDump`, that will be the only name defined in SysDump.py

Comment: @NedBatchelder I believe the OP means that importing this class also makes `_cPickle` et al available

Comment: @fge it wouldn't do that, so I'll be interested to hear what the OP meant.

Comment: @NedBatchelder it'll be available via _SysDump (as _SysDump._cPickle).

Comment: in libApi.py other than the class _SysDump() I have class abcd(): with a bunch of imports, class xyz(): with more imports. Like that I have many classes each with its own set of imports. I want to see only the imports inside class _SysDump() which is not happening

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: you still have not defined what you mean by "see".  Only one name is defined in your importing file.  What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, What I mean is the imports in other classes get defined to me which I dont want. What happens is when the imports from the non wanted class get defined the behavior of my program changes. So I want only the imports concerned to SyDump none else

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: I'm sorry, I don't yet understand how those imports affect your program.  Perhaps you could provide a more complete sample?  In any case, importing a module fully executes the imported Python file, there's no way for it to execute only part of it.

Comment: Sorry let me try,kindly bear with me. Let me state my problem in a different way. Assume I have two classes defined in libApi.py one is the class _SysDump(): and the other is class abcd():. Both of them have a set of imports. In SysDump.py I do from libApi import _SysDump and then run my code and it fails. I comment out class abcd and my program works. That means class abcd(): has adverse affect on  my program. However this libApi is accessed  by other programs and for them the imports under class abcd(): is relevant and not my class _SysDump(). That is the problem.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Ok, then you need to find out what is wrong with class abcd().  You haven't mentioned what the failure is, but this can definitely be solved.  Perhaps ask in the #python IRC channel on freenode?  Or ask a more complete question here, with the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Python's 'private' methods not actually private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private)

Answer (score 2):

Python has no notion of privacy.  If you are trying to hide information in one module from another module which imports it, you cannot.  That is a concept from other programming languages which has no parallel in Python.

Comment: To be clear: Of course, Python programmers do have that notion and there's a convention (underscore prefix) for indicating that intent. There's just no such thing in the language.

Comment: I agree but when we do specifically from libApi import _SysDump should'nt it mean From libApi.py go get me the imports inside the class _SysDump only?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: when you import a module, the entire module.py file is executed.  Then the names you want to import are defined in your file.  There is no way to execute only part of a Python file.