# Child method is run instead of parent's?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have following class inheritance schema:

```
object <- A <- B <- Z
```

Now each class will have public `setup()` method, which calls other "private" method `_configure()`, which contains loading code that I don't want to clutter up `setup()`.  The point is to make every class "know" how to set itself up, and do it before other executions.

So what I want when calling setup on Z's instance is to run *both* A's setup and B's setup (order is not particularly important now), while each setup using _configure as defined in its own class.

Now following script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.configured = []
        self.set_up = []

    def _configure(self):
        self.configured.append("A")

    def setup(self):
        self._configure()       # calls B._configure()!
        self.set_up.append("A")

class B(A):

    def _configure(self):
        self.configured.append("B")

    def setup(self):
        super(B, self).setup()
        self._configure()
        self.set_up.append("B")

class Z(B):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = Z()
    z.setup()
    print "configured: %s" % z.configured
    print "set up: %s" % z.set_up
```

runs `B._configure()` twice, therefore returns

```
me@here:~$ ./t.py 
configured: ['B', 'B']
set up: ['A', 'B']
me@here:~$
```

instead of `configured: ['A', 'B']...`.

Could somebody explain this to me?  How should I make sure that `A.setup` calls `A._configure`?

**Workaround**: What worked for now was replacing `self._configure` with `A._configure(self)`, but that seems ugly and non-OOP: now each class that could be potentially inherited should repeat its name with every method call?  Where is the beauty and brevity of `self`?

Comment: Your output says it called `B._configure` twice, not `A._configure`.

Comment: This looks like it works exactly as one would expect - in general, the child method is called, unless you're using `super`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, the necessary magic is called [name mangling](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/private_functions.html#fileinfo.private.1.1) or [name scrambling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private).

The solution is as simple as using **two underscores** in the name of the configuring method.  When Python sees such funny named method (or other attribute), it will *silently rename* it to `_A__configure`, so that proper method is called even if user (accidentally or not) overwrote it.

(Until now, I thought that "two underscores" are reserved for Python internals, humbly avoiding them all the time...)

Fixed code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.configured = []
        self.set_up = []

    def __configure(self):
        self.configured.append("A")

    def setup(self):
        self.__configure()
        self.set_up.append("A")

class B(A):

    def __configure(self):
        self.configured.append("B")

    def setup(self):
        super(B, self).setup()
        self.__configure()
        self.set_up.append("B")

class Z(B):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = Z()
    z.setup()
    print "configured: %s" % z.configured
    print "set up: %s" % z.set_up
```

returns the desired

```
me@here:~$ ./t.py 
configured: ['A', 'B']
set up: ['A', 'B']
me@here:~$
```

Comment: I gave you an "up" on this one, as "not doing polymorphism" when you don't want to is a known technique in some languages, like C++ (first of all, don't declare something virtual, which apparently python has by default for 100% of methods), but in others it isn't quite as obvious how to do it.  This is a demo of how in Python, and thus worth an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The `setup` method in class `B` calls `super`, so it calls the `setup` method from `A`... This is the order of execution of your methods:

```
Z.setup()
  B.setup()
    A.setup (via super)
      B._configure
        B.configured.append("B")
      B.setup.append("A")
    B._configure
      B.configured.append("B")
  B.set_up.append("B")
```

This means that `Z.setup` calls `B.setup` via inheritance, which calls `A.setup` via `super`, which calls `B._configure`. `B.setup` calls again `B._configure` and return after the `append`.

Hope this makes it clear (more or less)

**UPDATE:** Here's a little explanation of what's happening: You are defining a class `Z` which has a public method `setup` and a private method `_configure`. Those methods are not defined in `Z` class but on its parent, class `B`. But you can still call `Z.setup` and `Z._configure` thanks to inheritance.

Now, the `Z.setup` method uses the definition in `B` class in order to work. This calls `super` in order to call the code defined in `A.setup` while still being `Z`, so when the method `_configure` is called, which definition will be used? As we are `Z` (that is, `self` is an instance of `Z`), the method that will be called will be `Z._configure`, because that's what inheritence does.

Look at the code again: you are overwriting in `B` the `_configure` method first defined in `A`. As there's no call to `super` in `B._configure`, `A._configure` will never be called if the object is an instance of a class that inherits from `A`.

**TL;DR**: You can't call `A._configure` from `Z` if `B` defines `_configure` without calling super. That's inheritance. If you want to call `A.configure`, either don't overwrite the method in `B` or use `super`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think the question is why `A.setup` calls `B._configure` instead of `A._configure`.

Comment: Because `self` in that `A.setup` is B because of the use of `super` :)

Comment: @mrcasals ...so *how* can I make it call `A._configure`?

Comment: Seems I'm in quite a sad situation:  the whole point of _configure was to *hide* away the aspect of configuration, not to add something for all B's to worry about.  (I'll probably end up re-thinking the whole schema from scratch.)