# Private variables - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a little confused regarding how to make private variables in Python. I know it involves a double underscore but how do you know if it should be before the variable name or after?

So when would it be:

```
self.__name
```

As compared to:

```
__self.name
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to private properties of a class, you would use `self.__name` to access the private `__name` property. Using `__self` as the `self` variable would not have the effect of making the properties private.

You could have a private `__self` variable, for example a private variable of a module (which actually only requires a single underscore), but I assume this is not what you mean.

It's also worth noting that [a private variable is only semi-private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private).

Comment: Ok, I guess you could have a private `__self` variable technically, but that is so awkward, there are probably better names for it.

Answer (score 1):

It should always be `self.__name` if you want to follow the standard conventions.

`self` should always remained untampered. The naming convention is to prefix name with two underscores.

Comment: The `self` name is technically optional. It's only by convention that people use it, but it could be any valid variable name (though I would recommend following convention).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I've edited to say standard naming conventions, nevertheless, I doubt you would ever see code in the real world that doesn't follow this convention. Likewise, if there was code that didn't follow it, I would be very suspicious of using it.