# how to define equivalent of private method in python

Tags: java, python

i am new to python from java.

In java we would have something like

```
public void func1()
{
    func2();
}

private void func2(){}
```

However, in python i would like the equivalent

```
def func1(self):
    self.func2("haha")
    pass

def func2(str):
    pass
```

It throws me an error of takes exactly 1 argument(2 given)

I have checked for solutions such as using

```
def func1(self):
    self.func2("haha")
    pass

@classmethod 
def func2(str):
    pass
```

but it does not work

Taking out the self in func2 makes the global name func2 not defined.

How do i exactly resolve this situation.

Comment: Are these in a class or just functions in the global namespace?

Comment: There are no real private methods in python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private

Comment: Note, you could change your `@classmethod` to an `@staticmethod` and the code would likely work (although I can't guarantee it as I can't see the whole example class :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def func1(self):
        self._func2("haha")

    def _func2(self, arg):
        """This method is 'private' by convention because of the leading underscore in the name."""
        print arg

f = Foo()  # make an instance of the class.
f.func1()  # call it's public method.
```

Note that python has no *true* privacy.  If a user wants to call your method, they can.  It's just a fact of life that is described by the mantra ["We're all consenting adults here"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html).  However, if they call your method that is prefixed with an underscore, they deserve any breakages that they cause.

Also note that there are two levels of privacy:

```
def _private_method(self, ...):  # 'Normal'
    ...

def __private_with_name_mangling(self, ...):  # This name gets mangled to avoid collisions with base classes.
    ...
```

More info can be found in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that you want func2 to be private to (only exist in scope of) func1. If so, you can do this:

```
def func1(self, args):
    def func2(args):
        # do stuff
        pass
    return func2(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Foo:
  def method(self):
    self.static_method("haha")

  @classmethod 
  def static_method(clazz, str):
     print(str)

>>> Foo().method()
haha
>>> Foo.static_method('hi')
hi
```

Comment: You should be able to call your classmethod as `self.func2` from within `func1`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the example. Also added how to call func1 as a method and calling func2 as a 'static method'.