# how do you test private static method in module in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

we have a module of static methods in our python app. these methods use a lot of private (e.g: "__do_sub_task2(**args)") I would like to write unit tests for these private static methods within this module, but I am getting refernce errors.

is there a way to do this?

**update: adding scenario**

I have a module file named 'my_module.py'
contents of said file is as follows:

```
def public_method_foo(my_number):
  return __sub_method_bar(my_number * 10)

def __sub_method_bar(other_number)
  return other_number + 11
```

**update #2**
The reason I am asking this question is because I have a similar scenario as above, but when I add the following reference to my test.py module file:

```
from my_module import __sub_method_bar
```

and try to use it in my test, I get the following exception in my test

global name '_MyTests__sub_method_bar' is not defined

Comment: Aside - typically you do not write unit tests for private methods, but instead the public methods that use them.

Comment: but that would not be a unit test, it would be an integration test of both methods

Comment: Are these really `@staticmethod`s? Or do you mean something different by "static"? (And if so, what?)

Comment: Not necessarily. E.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have are not methods, not private, and not static; they're just plain old public functions in the module. So you call them the same way as any other function. For your example:

```
>>> my_module.__sub_method_bar(5)
```

That's it; nothing tricky.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* Well, there is *one* tricky thing, but it's probably not going to affect you here: If `my_module` doesn't have an `__all__`, and you do `from my_module import *`, you will not get any of the globals (including functions) whose names start with `_`. But normally your unit tests are going to `import my_module`, so this won't be relevant.</sub>

---

*Methods* are callables that are members of a *class*. And methods *can* be private ("private" in this sense means "visible only to this class, not even to super- or sub-classes", so it doesn't make sense for anything but methods). The tutorial chapter on [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) explains how private methods are implemented, with name-mangling. Methods (private or otherwise) can also be static ("static" in this context means "does not take the normal `self`", so again, it doesn't make sense for anything but methods). Either way, for a private method, you have to manually demangle the name to call it from outside:

```
>>> thingy = Thingy()
>>> thingy._Thingy__private_method(5)
>>> Thingy._Thingy__private_static_method(5)
```

Comment: my question is not about a class, it is about a private static method in a module

Comment: @NathanTregillus: That doesn't make any sense. A method is part of a class; that's what makes it a method. If it's just a function, modules don't have private functions the way classes have private methods; you just call it as `__do_sub_task2`. And I still don't know what you mean by "static".

Comment: please see example above

Comment: I think you'll need to provide an example, because static methods are part of classes. In fact, that is exactly what it means; a method moved into a class for the purpose of logical arrangement.

Comment: If this code `__do_sub_task2(**args)` (your example) is not in a class then it is neither a method nor private.

Comment: @NathanTregillus: OK, I've updated the answer to answer what you're actually trying to ask, and also to explain why it's not what you actually asked.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the newbish questions. only been working in Python for a month

Comment: ok now i am lost. this answer says there is no such thing as a private method, but then mentions __all__ will denote what is public. I have attempted the example provided with "from my_module import *" but no dice. I get the following error 
" global name 'my_module' is not defined"

Comment: @NathanTregillus: You're reading your own incorrect wording into things. First, the answer does not say "there is no such thing as a private method", it says there _is_ such a thing as a private method, but only methods can be private methods. The answer also does not say that `__all__` "will denote what is public"; there's a sense in which that's a reasonable thing to say, but not if you're using "public" to mean "the opposite of a private method", because that's not at all what it does.

Comment: @NathanTregillus: meanwhile, you did you change your attempt to `from my_module import *` when the answer explicitly says you probably shouldn't do that, and explains how it can add a new problem?

Comment: sorry, I missread the fine print that you SHOULDNT use "from blah import * " finally found a workaround. I did the following to my import:

Comment: from my_module import __sub_method_bar as sub_method_bar

Comment: when I used this aliased method, I was able to call the private method

Comment: just as a tip, _methodname is not really private. "private" in python is more a convention for devs :) [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private) is more about this.

Comment: @Reishin: He's asking about `__methodname`, which is different from `_methodname` (but only in methods, not in module-level functions).

Comment: @abarnert possibly you mean "in classes" :)

Comment: @Reishin: Yeah, either "in classes" or "for methods", not "in methods". Apparently much of talking at Germans today has broken my prepositions. :)

Comment: Thanks guys and/or gals, my previous experience with other languages, the terms methods and functions were interchangeable, so knowing there is a difference in python terminology is a good-to-know!

Comment: @NathanTregillus: Out of curiosity, which languages? I know that Dylan made a big deal out of "functions are just methods with no overloads", but I can't think of anything more mainstream.

Comment: was a C# developer for a long time. since everything in C# is in a class, you only had static methods, and member methods.

Comment: @NathanTregillus: Ah, C# just doesn't _have_ functions, like Java, so it forces you to write static methods as a substitute. You can actually do the exact same thing in Python—create a useless class, and define a bunch of methods with the `@staticmethod` decorator, and then use them instead of functions—but you don't have to, and very rarely want to.

Comment: @NathanTregillus: Except… aren't lambda expressions functions, not methods, in C#? Or are they just anonymous methods of anonymous classes?

Comment: you are right, but there are some strange closer like logic, like you can access outer scope variables within the lambda I believe. it gets complicated, and I avoided that stuff when possible

Comment: @NathanTregillus: Well, in Python, you can access outer scope variables from any function, so you can't really avoid it. But on the plus side, unlike C# and many other languages, Python's `lambda` works exactly the same as its `def` except for being anonymous and an expression, so you don't have to learn two completely different things. :)

Comment: awesome. Thanks @abarnert. I really appreciate people like you helping us newbies learn new stuff. It makes learning new languages fun.