# Python : how to sort a list in another program private class

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list which is in a private class, i can sort it without getting private but can't in private.

First i open data and split it in main.py, and set a list call StudentDL in main.py and call it to Student.py , if I private Student.py, I can't sort the StudentDL list in main.py .

How can I sort the StudentDL list in main.py or Student.py after private Student.py?

Main.py:

```
from Student import Student

StudentDL = []
file = open('markdata.dat', 'r')
line = file.readline()

while line != '':
    StudentRec = line.split('_')
    StudentDL.append(Student(int(StudentRec[0]),str(StudentRec[1]),
                            float(StudentRec[2]),
                            float(StudentRec[3])))
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
for e in StudentDL:
    print (e)
for e in sorted(StudentDL, key=lambda c:c.sID):
    print (e)
print('='*20)
for e in sorted(StudentDL, key=lambda c:c.n):
    print (Student.overall(e))
```

Student.py:

```
class Student(object):
    numStudent = 0 
    def __init__(self,studentID,name,cwmark,exammark):
        Student.numStudent += 1
        self.__sID = studentID
        self.__n = name
        self.__cwm = cwmark
        self.__exm = exammark
        self.__om = (cwmark*0.4)+(exammark*0.6)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%-15s%-27s%-10.2f%7.2f'%\
            (self.__sID,self.__n,self.__cwm,self.__exm)

    def overall(self):
        return '%-15s%-27s%-12.2f%-7.2f%8.2f'%\
            (self.__sID,self.__n,self.__cwm,self.__exm,self.__om)

    def getoverall(self):
        return float(self.__om)
```

markdata:

```
50123456_lam tai man_70.0_60.0_
50223456_li tai man_60.0_90.5_
50323456_wong tai man_34.5_30.0_
50423456_ng tai man_90.5_70.0_
50523456_lau tai man_86.0_92.4_
50623456_chui tai man_70.0_64.5_
50723456_lim tai man_64.5_60.0_
50823456_pok tai man_37.5_35.50_
50923456_kim tai man_92.4_60.0_
50023456_tsang tai man_15.0_20.0_
50999999_chan peter_100.00_80.00_
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect to be able to access private attributes from outside the class? [The whole point of private attributes is to prevent that](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) (Python [makes it easy to work around it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70528/364696), but you're explicitly violating encapsulation when you do it).

If the variables should be logically readable, with privacy being used primarily to prevent writes, `Student` can [declare `@property` accessors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Student(object):
    numStudent = 0 
    def __init__(self,studentID,name,cwmark,exammark):
        ...

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n

    @property
    def sID(self):
        return self.__sID
```

If that protection isn't needed though, then just declare your attributes without the leading `__` in the first place, and leave them public.

Comment: I know that my question is so silly .. But my teacher told use to submit the program with private class and have a sort function . The tips he gives is sort it in private class , I am so confuse what to do  ...

Comment: @WongYatCheongJacky: Did your teacher perhaps mean to make class instances comparable by defining `__lt__` and [the other rich comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)? That allows you to define a natural ordering of the class instances, and since `__lt__` is defined on the class, it has access to private members. Similarly, defining `@property` accessors would leave the underlying attributes private, while providing public read-only access (which would allow you to define `key` functions in terms of the properties).

Comment: [link](https://dpaste.de/jOrJ) and [link](https://dpaste.de/t0bD) i try to use 
  __lt__     method but show a error on TypeError: __lt__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Comment: @WongYatCheongJacky: You don't call `__lt__` directly (it's not forbidden, but it's silly to do so, and in the scenario you used it, makes no sense). It's just a function that gets called automatically when you test `studenta < studentb`, and Python's sorting functions use it implicitly as the default comparison when no `key` function is defined (or the object is part of the `key`). If `__lt__` is correctly defined, you just do `for e in sorted(StudentDL):` without passing a `key` function at all, and you'll iterate in sorted order.