# Need to block some of the methods from the parent class

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a Base class with all the common methods. How can I select only the selected methods from this base class and build a child class?

I am not sure how can I make only the required methods available in the child class.

Sample code to explain what I am trying to do

```
Class Baseclass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method_1(self):
       pass

    def method_2(self):
       pass


Class Child(Baseclass):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Here in the `Child` class, If I need only `method_1`, how can I block the `method_2` call?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70528/1639625

Comment: Design issue - if Child is not supposed to support __all__ of BaseClass's API, then Child should not inherit from BaseClass, but from another class that only implements method_1 and is the parent for both BaseClass and Child.

Comment: "Block" the method(s) in what sense?

Comment: @martineau, "Block" means, I want to make some of the methods unavailable for some child classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking access to `Baseclass` method(s) in its child classes is against [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is one of main reasons why inheritance exists - substitution of base type by its subtypes with same interface.

If you just want your `Child` classes to have different subsets of `Baseclass` methods right approach would be to break `Baseclass` into mixins (classes) implementing those common methods (it doesn't have to be one mixin per method - you can group them logically by responsibilities) and then use multiple inheritance to create classes with desired sets of features:

```py
class BaseAddMixin:
  def add(self, a, b):
    return a + b

class BaseSubMixin:
  def sub(self, a, b):
    return a - b 

class BaseMulMixin:
  def mul(self, a, b):
    return a * b

# Now we want child class that has add() and mul() but not sub() method
class AddMulChild(BaseAddMixin, BaseMulMixin):
  def do_something(self, a, b):
    return self.mul(a, b) + self.add(a, b)

# We can also have child class that has add() and sub() only
class AddSubChild(BaseAddMixin, BaseSubMixin):
  def do_something(self, a, b):
    return self.add(a, b) * self.sub(a, b)
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance is __not__ "composition" - composition  (or more exactly "composition/delegation") is when an object `a` has an object `b` as attribute ("composition") and delegates parts of it's operations to this object ("delegation").

Comment: Thanks for this valuable comment, I was used to wrong terminology. I corrected my answer.