# Python: Need to create immutable constants to use in other files of the code

Tags: python-3.x

I would like create few constants which should be immutable like int in a separate file which can be import using a class.

I tried to create class but it's not working for me.

```
class test_const:
    const1 = [5, 6, 7]
    const2 = 8

>>> test_const.const1
[5, 6, 7]
>>> test_const.const1 = "overwrite"
>>> test_const.const1
"overwrite"
```

When we overwrite the constant it should through error like
X SyntaxError: can't assign to const1 ( because const1 is immutable)

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private