# Python private instance variable behavior

Tags: python, class, private-members

The following piece of code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 123
    def getV(self):
        return self.__var
a = A()
a.__var = 10
print a.getVar(), a.__var
```

prints `123 10`. Why does this behavior occur? I would expect a.getVar() to print out 10. Does the class internally interpret self.__var as self._A__var?

Comment: You're right. Read here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Comment: This feature is called name mangeling and all attributes starting with double underscore are subject to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Python's 'private' methods not actually private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double underscore attributes in Python has a special effect, it does "name mangling" that is it converts the attribute `__var` to `_A__var` i.e. `_<classname>__<attributename>` at runtime.

In your example when you assign `10` to the attribute `__var` of `a` object, it is essentially creating a **new attribute** `__var` and not modifying the `self.__var`. This is because the `self.__var` is now `_A__var` due to name mangling.

This can be seen if you print the `__dict__` of the `a` object:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 123
    def getV(self):
        return self.__var
a = A()
print (a.__dict__)

>> {'_A__var': 123}
```

If you don't assign any value to `__var` and try to print it directly, it will result in an `AttributeError`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 123
    def getV(self):
        return self.__var
a = A()
print (a.__var)

>> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__var'
```

Now if you try to assign to the new mangled attribute name, you would get the right result (but this process is meant to prevent accidental usage of such variables):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 123
    def getV(self):
        return self.__var
a = A()
a._A__var = 10
print (a.getV())

>> 10
```