# Understand `_html_output()` from Django Forms Source Code

Tags: django, django-forms

Below source code is from [django/forms/forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca04659b4b3f042c1bc7e557c25ed91e3c56c745/django/forms/forms.py#L211)

```
class BaseForm(RenderableFormMixin):
    def _html_output(self, normal_row, error_row, row_ender, help_text_html, errors_on_separate_row):
    "Output HTML. Used by as_table(), as_ul(), as_p()."
```

How is this private method `_html_output()` used / invoked by `as_table(), as_ul(), as_p()` please ? I did not find out from the source code.

Comment: Please read about [private methods in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private)

Comment: thanks for sharing, I reviewed the link you shared, which does not clear my confusion. I believe that I understand how `private method` work and how to use it. As per my understanding, when any `methods` use `private methods`, they should explicitly invoke `private methods` during method definition. But I did not find that in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is no longer used

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#id2

> Since form rendering now uses the template engine, the undocumented BaseForm._html_output() helper method is deprecated